# How to convert a nested Python dict to object?

Tags: python, object, dictionary

I'm searching for an elegant way to get data using attribute access on a dict with some nested dicts and lists (i.e. javascript-style object syntax).

For example:

```
>>> d = {'a': 1, 'b': {'c': 2}, 'd': ["hi", {'foo': "bar"}]}
```

Should be accessible in this way:

```
>>> x = dict2obj(d)
>>> x.a
1
>>> x.b.c
2
>>> x.d[1].foo
bar
```

I think, this is not possible without recursion, but what would be a nice way to get an object style for dicts?

Comment: I was trying to do something similar recently, but a recurring dictionary key ("from" - which is a Python keyword) prevented me from going through with it. Because as soon as you tried using "x.from" to access that attribute you'd get a syntax error.

Comment: that's a problem indeed, but i can abandon on "from" to make life easier in accessing large dict constructs :)

typing x['a']['d'][1]['foo'] is really annoying, so x.a.d[1].foo rules. if you need from, you can access it via getattr(x, 'from') or use _from as attribute instead.

Comment: `from_` rather than `_from` according to [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#function-and-method-arguments).

Comment: You can use `getattr(x, 'from')` instead of renaming the attribute.

Comment: Most of these "solutions" don't seem to work (even the accepted one, doesn't allow nested `d1.b.c`), I think it's clear you should be using something from a library, e.g. [namedtuple from collections](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html?highlight=collections#namedtuple-factory-function-for-tuples-with-named-fields), as [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9413295/1240268) suggests, ...

Comment: Bunch - Use a Python dict like an object: http://thechangelog.com/bunch-lets-use-python-dict-like-object/

Answer (score 749, accepted):

**Update:** In Python 2.6 and onwards, consider whether the [`namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) data structure suits your needs:

```
>>> from collections import namedtuple
>>> MyStruct = namedtuple('MyStruct', 'a b d')
>>> s = MyStruct(a=1, b={'c': 2}, d=['hi'])
>>> s
MyStruct(a=1, b={'c': 2}, d=['hi'])
>>> s.a
1
>>> s.b
{'c': 2}
>>> s.c
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'MyStruct' object has no attribute 'c'
>>> s.d
['hi']
```

The alternative (original answer contents) is:

```
class Struct:
    def __init__(self, **entries):
        self.__dict__.update(entries)
```

Then, you can use:

```
>>> args = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}
>>> s = Struct(**args)
>>> s
<__main__.Struct instance at 0x01D6A738>
>>> s.a
1
>>> s.b
2
```

Comment: Same here - this is particularly useful for reconstructing Python objects from document oriented databases like MongoDB.

Comment: To get prettier printing add:
    
        def __repr__(self):
            return '<%s>' % str('\n  '.join('%s : %s' % (k, repr(v)) for (k, v) in self.__dict__.iteritems()))

Comment: Will this work with nested dictionaries? and dicts containing objects and or list etc. Are there any catches?

Comment: @Sam S: it won't create nested `Struct`s from nested dictionaries, but in general the type of the value can be anything. Key is restricted to being suitable for an object slot

Comment: Thanks! I was dismayed when passing user-defined objects through xmlrpclib only to find them converted into a dict representation.  This useful code rectifies that issue.

Comment: This helps access useful dicts in deeply nested JSON.

Comment: -1 because a) it doesn't work for nested dicts, which the question clearly asked for, and b) the same functionality currently exists in standard libraries in `argparse.Namespace` (which has also defined `__eq__`, `__ne__`, `__contains__`).

Comment: Do you have a solution for nested dictionaries, too?

Comment: Future readers - refer to @umbrae's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9413295/116047) with the namedtuple

Comment: For nested dictionaries, look at one of the other Struct() answers below with the recursive _wrap() function.

Comment: @six8 Fixed formatting (mostly): `def __repr__(self): return '<%s>' % str('\n '.join('%s : %s' % (k, repr(v)) for (k, v) in self.__dict__.iteritems()))`

Comment: So... this requires you to manually reformat the dictionary into keyword arguments?  What if you have no idea what the dictionary will look like?

Answer (score 182):

Surprisingly no one has mentioned [Bunch](https://github.com/dsc/bunch). This library is exclusively meant to provide attribute style access to dict objects and does exactly what the OP wants. A demonstration:

```
>>> from bunch import bunchify
>>> d = {'a': 1, 'b': {'c': 2}, 'd': ["hi", {'foo': "bar"}]}
>>> x = bunchify(d)
>>> x.a
1
>>> x.b.c
2
>>> x.d[1].foo
'bar'
```

A Python 3 library is available at https://github.com/Infinidat/munch - Credit goes to [codyzu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/880509/codyzu)

```
>>> from munch import DefaultMunch
>>> d = {'a': 1, 'b': {'c': 2}, 'd': ["hi", {'foo': "bar"}]}
>>> obj = DefaultMunch.fromDict(d)
>>> obj.b.c
2
>>> obj.a
1
>>> obj.d[1].foo
'bar'
```

Comment: And there is a python 3 compatible (appears to be 2.6-3.4) branch of Bunch named Munch: https://github.com/Infinidat/munch

Comment: Bunch is the best solution of all of these because it supports multiple types of serialization well, and is maintained. Great, thank you. I wish the python3 version was named the same thing, buecause why not.

Comment: So just a forewarning, Bunch and Attrdict as well for that matter are very slow.  They consumed about 1/3 and 1/2 of my request time respectively when they saw frequent use in our application.  Definitely not something to ignore.  Talk more about it http://stackoverflow.com/a/31569634/364604.

Comment: While this does allow object-like access to dicts, it does so via __getattr__.  This makes introspection in smart REPLs like IPython difficult.

Comment: Curious how this compares to JSONpath https://github.com/kennknowles/python-jsonpath-rw

Comment: if use python 2.+ => https://pypi.org/project/bunch/    if use python 3.+ => https://pypi.org/project/munch/                                                                                           As you are in python3 , use dict.items() instead of dict.iteritems()

iteritems() was removed in python3, so you can't use this method anymore.

Comment: AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'iteritems'

Answer (score 140):

```
class obj(object):
    def __init__(self, d):
        for k, v in d.items():
            if isinstance(k, (list, tuple)):
                setattr(self, k, [obj(x) if isinstance(x, dict) else x for x in v])
            else:
                setattr(self, k, obj(v) if isinstance(v, dict) else v)

>>> d = {'a': 1, 'b': {'c': 2}, 'd': ["hi", {'foo': "bar"}]}
>>> x = obj(d)
>>> x.b.c
2
>>> x.d[1].foo
'bar'
```

Comment: Good!  I'd replace .items() by .iteritems(), though, for a smaller memory footprint.

Comment: If not an OP requirement, this is not an issue - but note that this won't recursively process objects in lists within lists.

Comment: Nice!  But then the dict needs to be complete when you create the class... I guess that works... you could create another instance if you modify the dict.  Good stuff!

Comment: Thank you this worked well for me. Here is the reverse jic anyone can use it.

    def todict(self):
        d = {}
        for attr in dir(self):
            if attr.startswith('__') or  attr == 'todict':
                continue
            val = getattr(self, attr)
            if isinstance(val, (list, tuple)):
               d[attr] = [x.todict() if isinstance(x, Bag) else x for x in val]
            else:
               d[attr] = val.todict() if isinstance(val, Bag) else val
        return d

Comment: I realise this is an old answer, but these days it would be better to use an [abstract base class](http://docs.python.org/2/library/abc.html) instead of that ugly line `if isinstance(b, (list, tuple)):`

Comment: >>> x = {}; x['a'] = x; obj(x) .... RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded. Make sure there are no circular references in your (nested) dict structure.

Comment: Tip: Have the `obj` class inherit from `argparse.Namespace` for additional features like readable string representation.

Comment: @wim: What abstract base class from the `collections` module would you use to replace `isinstance(b, (list, tuple))`?

Comment: Depending on the use case, usually we would check that it is _not_ a string type but that it _is_ a Sequence type

Comment: I am wondering how an answer with a bug got 137 positive votes... `if isinstance(k, (list, tuple)):`: **k** is the key, you should test **v** instead!

Comment: lol I have the same question as ishahak. Came here to say this.

Answer (score 77):

```
x = type('new_dict', (object,), d)
```

then add recursion to this and you're done.

**edit** this is how I'd implement it:

```
>>> d
{'a': 1, 'b': {'c': 2}, 'd': ['hi', {'foo': 'bar'}]}
>>> def obj_dic(d):
    top = type('new', (object,), d)
    seqs = tuple, list, set, frozenset
    for i, j in d.items():
        if isinstance(j, dict):
            setattr(top, i, obj_dic(j))
        elif isinstance(j, seqs):
            setattr(top, i, 
                type(j)(obj_dic(sj) if isinstance(sj, dict) else sj for sj in j))
        else:
            setattr(top, i, j)
    return top

>>> x = obj_dic(d)
>>> x.a
1
>>> x.b.c
2
>>> x.d[1].foo
'bar'
```

Comment: Why are you creating type-objects and not instantiating them? Wouldn't that be more logical? I mean, why not do `top_instance = top()` and returning that where you return `top`?

Comment: Nice for the "leaf" data, but the examples conveniently leave out "twigs" like `x` and `x.b` which return ugly `<class '__main__.new'>`

Answer (score 68):

```
# Applies to Python-3 Standard Library
class Struct(object):
    def __init__(self, data):
        for name, value in data.items():
            setattr(self, name, self._wrap(value))

    def _wrap(self, value):
        if isinstance(value, (tuple, list, set, frozenset)): 
            return type(value)([self._wrap(v) for v in value])
        else:
            return Struct(value) if isinstance(value, dict) else value


# Applies to Python-2 Standard Library
class Struct(object):
    def __init__(self, data):
        for name, value in data.iteritems():
            setattr(self, name, self._wrap(value))

    def _wrap(self, value):
        if isinstance(value, (tuple, list, set, frozenset)): 
            return type(value)([self._wrap(v) for v in value])
        else:
            return Struct(value) if isinstance(value, dict) else value
```

Can be used with any sequence/dict/value structure of any depth.

Comment: This should be the answer.  It works well for nesting.  You can use this as an object_hook for json.load() as well.

Comment: Similar to SilentGhost's functional answer from 2009 --the leaf node data is accessible, but the parent/twigs display as object references.  To pretty-print, `def __repr__(self): return '{%s}' % str(', '.join("'%s': %s" % (k, repr(v)) for (k, v) in self.__dict__.iteritems()))`

Comment: Python 3.x users: it's just `.items()` instead of `.iteritems()` in line 4. (The function was renamed, but does [essentialy the same](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10458567/2525299))

Comment: Works perfect for nested objects, thanks! As a comment newbies as I, for python3 iteritems() must be changed to items()

Comment: The pretty-print equivalent for python 3 is: `def __repr__(self): return ("{ " + str(", ".join([f"'{k}': {v}" for k, v in [(k, repr(v)) for (k, v) in self.__dict__.items()]])) + " }")`

Answer (score 57):

There's a 
collection helper called [`namedtuple`](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html?highlight=collections#namedtuple-factory-function-for-tuples-with-named-fields), that can do this for you:

```
from collections import namedtuple

d_named = namedtuple('Struct', d.keys())(*d.values())

In [7]: d_named
Out[7]: Struct(a=1, b={'c': 2}, d=['hi', {'foo': 'bar'}])

In [8]: d_named.a
Out[8]: 1
```

Comment: This does not answer the question of recursion for the nested dicts.

Comment: you can't modify namedtuples.

Comment: Can we guarantee that the order of the list returned by keys() and values() match in order? I mean, if it is a OrderedDict, yes. But a standard dict? I know that CPython 3.6+ and PyPy "compact" dicts are ordered, but quoting documentation: "The order-preserving aspect of this new implementation is considered an implementation detail and should not be relied upon"

Comment: this also works `d_named = namedtuple('Struct', d)(**d)`

Answer (score 39):

If your dict is coming from `json.loads()`, you can turn it into an object instead (rather than a dict) in one line:

```
import json
from collections import namedtuple

json.loads(data, object_hook=lambda d: namedtuple('X', d.keys())(*d.values()))
```

See also [How to convert JSON data into a Python object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6578986/how-to-convert-json-data-into-a-python-object/15882054#15882054).

Comment: Seems to be much slower than regular `.loads` if you have a huge JSON object

Comment: this is the answer. thanks mate.

Answer (score 36):

You can leverage the **`json` module** of the standard library with a **custom object hook**:

```
import json

class obj(object):
    def __init__(self, dict_):
        self.__dict__.update(dict_)

def dict2obj(d):
    return json.loads(json.dumps(d), object_hook=obj)
```

Example usage:

```
>>> d = {'a': 1, 'b': {'c': 2}, 'd': ['hi', {'foo': 'bar'}]}
>>> o = dict2obj(d)
>>> o.a
1
>>> o.b.c
2
>>> o.d[0]
u'hi'
>>> o.d[1].foo
u'bar'
```

And it is **not strictly read-only** as it is with `namedtuple`, i.e. you can change values – not structure:

```
>>> o.b.c = 3
>>> o.b.c
3
```

Comment: Best answer by far

Comment: I like the idea to use the json loading mechanism for nested elements. But we already have a dict and I don't like the fact the one needs to create a string out of it to map it into an object. I would rather like to have a solution that creates objects directly from a dict.

Comment: Needs to convert to string first but pretty generic as one could extend it via `json.JSONEncoder` and `object_hook`.

Answer (score 31):

Taking what I feel are the best aspects of the previous examples, here's what I came up with:

```
class Struct:
    """The recursive class for building and representing objects with."""

    def __init__(self, obj):
        for k, v in obj.items():
            if isinstance(v, dict):
                setattr(self, k, Struct(v))
            else:
                setattr(self, k, v)

    def __getitem__(self, val):
        return self.__dict__[val]

    def __repr__(self):
        return '{%s}' % str(', '.join('%s : %s' % (k, repr(v)) for (k, v) in self.__dict__.items()))
```

Comment: Note that the constructor can be shortened to:

    `def __init__(self, dct):
        for k, v in dct.iteritems():
            setattr(self, k, isinstance(v, dict) and self.__class__(v) or v)`

which also removes the explicit call to `Struct`

Comment: I'd rather not downvote my own answer, but looking back on this I've noticed that it doesn't recurse into sequence types. x.d[1].foo fails in this case.

Comment: the `isinstance(v, dict)` check would be better as `isinstance(v, collections.Mapping)` so it can handle future dict-like things

Answer (score 23):

I ended up trying BOTH the [AttrDict](https://github.com/bcj/AttrDict) and the [Bunch](https://github.com/dsc/bunch) libraries and found them to be way too slow for my uses.  After a friend and I looked into it, we found that the main method for writing these libraries results in the library aggressively recursing through a nested object and making copies of the dictionary object throughout.  With this in mind, we made two key changes.  1) We made attributes lazy-loaded 2) instead of creating copies of a dictionary object, we create copies of a light-weight proxy object.  This is the final implementation.  The performance increase of using this code is incredible.  When using AttrDict or Bunch, these two libraries alone consumed 1/2 and 1/3 respectively of my request time(what!?).  This code reduced that time to almost nothing(somewhere in the range of 0.5ms).  This of course depends on your needs, but if you are using this functionality quite a bit in your code, definitely go with something simple like this.

```
class DictProxy(object):
    def __init__(self, obj):
        self.obj = obj

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return wrap(self.obj[key])

    def __getattr__(self, key):
        try:
            return wrap(getattr(self.obj, key))
        except AttributeError:
            try:
                return self[key]
            except KeyError:
                raise AttributeError(key)

    # you probably also want to proxy important list properties along like
    # items(), iteritems() and __len__

class ListProxy(object):
    def __init__(self, obj):
        self.obj = obj

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        return wrap(self.obj[key])

    # you probably also want to proxy important list properties along like
    # __iter__ and __len__

def wrap(value):
    if isinstance(value, dict):
        return DictProxy(value)
    if isinstance(value, (tuple, list)):
        return ListProxy(value)
    return value
```

See the original implementation [here](https://gist.github.com/mmerickel/ff4c6faf867d72c1f19c) by https://stackoverflow.com/users/704327/michael-merickel.

The other thing to note, is that this implementation is pretty simple and doesn't implement all of the methods you might need.  You'll need to write those as required on the DictProxy or ListProxy objects.

Comment: Note that for Python 3.10 and above, you'll need to use `Mapping` and `Sequence` from `collections.abc` instead of `collections`

Answer (score 20):

If you want to access dict keys as an object (or as a dict for difficult keys), do it recursively, and also be able to update the original dict, you could do:

```
class Dictate(object):
    """Object view of a dict, updating the passed in dict when values are set
    or deleted. "Dictate" the contents of a dict...: """

    def __init__(self, d):
        # since __setattr__ is overridden, self.__dict = d doesn't work
        object.__setattr__(self, '_Dictate__dict', d)

    # Dictionary-like access / updates
    def __getitem__(self, name):
        value = self.__dict[name]
        if isinstance(value, dict):  # recursively view sub-dicts as objects
            value = Dictate(value)
        return value

    def __setitem__(self, name, value):
        self.__dict[name] = value
    def __delitem__(self, name):
        del self.__dict[name]

    # Object-like access / updates
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return self[name]

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        self[name] = value
    def __delattr__(self, name):
        del self[name]

    def __repr__(self):
        return "%s(%r)" % (type(self).__name__, self.__dict)
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.__dict)
```

Example usage:

```
d = {'a': 'b', 1: 2}
dd = Dictate(d)
assert dd.a == 'b'  # Access like an object
assert dd[1] == 2  # Access like a dict
# Updates affect d
dd.c = 'd'
assert d['c'] == 'd'
del dd.a
del dd[1]
# Inner dicts are mapped
dd.e = {}
dd.e.f = 'g'
assert dd['e'].f == 'g'
assert d == {'c': 'd', 'e': {'f': 'g'}}
```

Answer (score 16):

```
>>> def dict2obj(d):
        if isinstance(d, list):
            d = [dict2obj(x) for x in d]
        if not isinstance(d, dict):
            return d
        class C(object):
            pass
        o = C()
        for k in d:
            o.__dict__[k] = dict2obj(d[k])
        return o


>>> d = {'a': 1, 'b': {'c': 2}, 'd': ["hi", {'foo': "bar"}]}
>>> x = dict2obj(d)
>>> x.a
1
>>> x.b.c
2
>>> x.d[1].foo
'bar'
```

Answer (score 13):

In 2021, use pydantic BaseModel - will convert nested dicts and nested json objects to python objects and vice versa:

https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/models/

```
>>> class Foo(BaseModel):
...     count: int
...     size: float = None
... 
>>> 
>>> class Bar(BaseModel):
...     apple = 'x'
...     banana = 'y'
... 
>>> 
>>> class Spam(BaseModel):
...     foo: Foo
...     bars: List[Bar]
... 
>>> 
>>> m = Spam(foo={'count': 4}, bars=[{'apple': 'x1'}, {'apple': 'x2'}])
```

**Object to dict**

```
>>> print(m.dict())
{'foo': {'count': 4, 'size': None}, 'bars': [{'apple': 'x1', 'banana': 'y'}, {'apple': 'x2', 'banana': 'y'}]}
```

**Object to JSON**

```
>>> print(m.json())
{"foo": {"count": 4, "size": null}, "bars": [{"apple": "x1", "banana": "y"}, {"apple": "x2", "banana": "y"}]}
```

**Dict to object**

```
>>> spam = Spam.parse_obj({'foo': {'count': 4, 'size': None}, 'bars': [{'apple': 'x1', 'banana': 'y'}, {'apple': 'x2', 'banana': 'y2'}]})
>>> spam
Spam(foo=Foo(count=4, size=None), bars=[Bar(apple='x1', banana='y'), Bar(apple='x2', banana='y2')])
```

**JSON to object**

```
>>> spam = Spam.parse_raw('{"foo": {"count": 4, "size": null}, "bars": [{"apple": "x1", "banana": "y"}, {"apple": "x2", "banana": "y"}]}')
>>> spam
Spam(foo=Foo(count=4, size=None), bars=[Bar(apple='x1', banana='y'), Bar(apple='x2', banana='y')])
```

Comment: This one should be the accepted answer. Thank you so much! I spent an hour searching for a solution that plays nicely with type-annotated classes.

Comment: While this works if you know the structure of the dict, you're not able to create a pydantic model dynamically. For that you need to call `create_model(__model_name="ModelName", **some_dict)`. This however only works with the top level, so you have to make it generate pydantic model recursively..
But creating pydantic models is slower than other modules such as named_tuples or dataclasses.

Comment: What is the overhead of pydantic compared to munch compared to namedtuples?

Answer (score 11):

`x.__dict__.update(d)` should do fine.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but what is x? the dict or a standard object? could you give me a hint please.

Comment: x is your object. Every object has a __dict__. By updating the __dict__ of a object you are actually updating the key vars in it.

Comment: The bold words are _ _ dict _ _

Comment: This won't handle nested dictionaries.

Comment: Not every object has a `__dict__`: try `object().__dict__` and you'll get `AttributeError: 'object' object has no attribute '__dict__'`

Comment: @WillManley you are right. Any python code can also define such a type using `__slots__`.

Answer (score 9):

Typically you want to mirror dict hierarchy into your object but not list or tuples which are typically at lowest level. So this is how I did this:

```
class defDictToObject(object):

    def __init__(self, myDict):
        for key, value in myDict.items():
            if type(value) == dict:
                setattr(self, key, defDictToObject(value))
            else:
                setattr(self, key, value)
```

So we do:

```
myDict = { 'a': 1,
           'b': { 
              'b1': {'x': 1,
                    'y': 2} },
           'c': ['hi', 'bar'] 
         }
```

and get:

`x.b.b1.x` 1

`x.c` ['hi', 'bar']

Answer (score 8):

This should get your started:

```
class dict2obj(object):
    def __init__(self, d):
        self.__dict__['d'] = d

    def __getattr__(self, key):
        value = self.__dict__['d'][key]
        if type(value) == type({}):
            return dict2obj(value)

        return value

d = {'a': 1, 'b': {'c': 2}, 'd': ["hi", {'foo': "bar"}]}

x = dict2obj(d)
print x.a
print x.b.c
print x.d[1].foo
```

It doesn't work for lists, yet. You'll have to wrap the lists in a UserList and overload `__getitem__` to wrap dicts.

Comment: To make it work for lists, use the `if isinstance(d, list)` clause from `Anon`'s answer.

Answer (score 8):

I know there's already a lot of answers here already and I'm late to the party but this method will recursively and 'in place' convert a dictionary to an object-like structure... Works in 3.x.x

```
def dictToObject(d):
    for k,v in d.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            d[k] = dictToObject(v)
    return namedtuple('object', d.keys())(*d.values())

# Dictionary created from JSON file
d = {
    'primaryKey': 'id', 
    'metadata': 
        {
            'rows': 0, 
            'lastID': 0
        }, 
    'columns': 
        {
            'col2': {
                'dataType': 'string', 
                'name': 'addressLine1'
            }, 
            'col1': {
                'datatype': 'string', 
                'name': 'postcode'
            }, 
            'col3': {
                'dataType': 'string', 
                'name': 'addressLine2'
            }, 
            'col0': {
                'datatype': 'integer', 
                'name': 'id'
            }, 
            'col4': {
                'dataType': 'string', 
                'name': 'contactNumber'
            }
        }, 
        'secondaryKeys': {}
}

d1 = dictToObject(d)
d1.columns.col1 # == object(datatype='string', name='postcode')
d1.metadata.rows # == 0
```

Comment: What do you mean "object-like structure"?

Comment: Object-like because of the duck typing principle. What I mean is you can access its properties like you would if it was an instance of a class. but it's NOT an object in that sense, it's a named tuple.

Answer (score 6):

```
from mock import Mock
d = {'a': 1, 'b': {'c': 2}, 'd': ["hi", {'foo': "bar"}]}
my_data = Mock(**d)

# We got
# my_data.a == 1
```

Comment: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mock'`.

Comment: `mock` was a third party package, [now incorporated into unittest](https://pypi.org/project/mock/). `from unittest.mock import Mock` should work. One downside is, if your code is production code, it now depends on what should theoretically be just test code. Another is, this only works for shallow dictionaries. But, at the top level, a nested dictionary gets returned correctly, unlike many of the answers above.

Answer (score 6):

This also works well too

```
class DObj(object):
    pass

dobj = Dobj()
dobj.__dict__ = {'a': 'aaa', 'b': 'bbb'}

print dobj.a
>>> aaa
print dobj.b
>>> bbb
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. You have a typo on line 4, it should be: dobj = DObj(). When trying to run this code in another env I get this error: `TypeError: 'DObj' object is not subscriptable` , do you know a fix for this? :)

Comment: Nvm, I found the cause, my dictionary is not flat.

Answer (score 6):

The simplest way would be using [`collections.namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple).

I find the following 4-liner the most beautiful, which supports nested dictionaries:

```
def dict_to_namedtuple(typename, data):
    return namedtuple(typename, data.keys())(
        *(dict_to_namedtuple(typename + '_' + k, v) if isinstance(v, dict) else v for k, v in data.items())
    )
```

The output will look good as well:

```
>>> nt = dict_to_namedtuple('config', {
...     'path': '/app',
...     'debug': {'level': 'error', 'stream': 'stdout'}
... })

>>> print(nt)
config(path='/app', debug=config_debug(level='error', stream='stdout'))

>>> print(nt.debug.level)
'error'
```

Answer (score 4):

Let me explain a solution I **almost** used some time ago. But first, the reason I did not is illustrated by the fact that the following code:

```
d = {'from': 1}
x = dict2obj(d)

print x.from
```

gives this error:

```
  File "test.py", line 20
    print x.from == 1
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Because "from" is a Python keyword there are certain dictionary keys you cannot allow.

---

Now my solution allows access to the dictionary items by using their names directly. But it also allows you to use "dictionary semantics". Here is the code with example usage:

```
class dict2obj(dict):
    def __init__(self, dict_):
        super(dict2obj, self).__init__(dict_)
        for key in self:
            item = self[key]
            if isinstance(item, list):
                for idx, it in enumerate(item):
                    if isinstance(it, dict):
                        item[idx] = dict2obj(it)
            elif isinstance(item, dict):
                self[key] = dict2obj(item)

    def __getattr__(self, key):
        return self[key]

d = {'a': 1, 'b': {'c': 2}, 'd': ["hi", {'foo': "bar"}]}

x = dict2obj(d)

assert x.a == x['a'] == 1
assert x.b.c == x['b']['c'] == 2
assert x.d[1].foo == x['d'][1]['foo'] == "bar"
```

Comment: class Struct:
        def __init__(self, **entries): 
            self.__dict__.update(entries)

Answer (score 4):

Old Q&A, but I get something more to talk. Seems no one talk about recursive dict. This is my code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

class Object( dict ):
    def __init__( self, data = None ):
        super( Object, self ).__init__()
        if data:
            self.__update( data, {} )

    def __update( self, data, did ):
        dataid = id(data)
        did[ dataid ] = self

        for k in data:
            dkid = id(data[k])
            if did.has_key(dkid):
                self[k] = did[dkid]
            elif isinstance( data[k], Object ):
                self[k] = data[k]
            elif isinstance( data[k], dict ):
                obj = Object()
                obj.__update( data[k], did )
                self[k] = obj
                obj = None
            else:
                self[k] = data[k]

    def __getattr__( self, key ):
        return self.get( key, None )

    def __setattr__( self, key, value ):
        if isinstance(value,dict):
            self[key] = Object( value )
        else:
            self[key] = value

    def update( self, *args ):
        for obj in args:
            for k in obj:
                if isinstance(obj[k],dict):
                    self[k] = Object( obj[k] )
                else:
                    self[k] = obj[k]
        return self

    def merge( self, *args ):
        for obj in args:
            for k in obj:
                if self.has_key(k):
                    if isinstance(self[k],list) and isinstance(obj[k],list):
                        self[k] += obj[k]
                    elif isinstance(self[k],list):
                        self[k].append( obj[k] )
                    elif isinstance(obj[k],list):
                        self[k] = [self[k]] + obj[k]
                    elif isinstance(self[k],Object) and isinstance(obj[k],Object):
                        self[k].merge( obj[k] )
                    elif isinstance(self[k],Object) and isinstance(obj[k],dict):
                        self[k].merge( obj[k] )
                    else:
                        self[k] = [ self[k], obj[k] ]
                else:
                    if isinstance(obj[k],dict):
                        self[k] = Object( obj[k] )
                    else:
                        self[k] = obj[k]
        return self

def test01():
    class UObject( Object ):
        pass
    obj = Object({1:2})
    d = {}
    d.update({
        "a": 1,
        "b": {
            "c": 2,
            "d": [ 3, 4, 5 ],
            "e": [ [6,7], (8,9) ],
            "self": d,
        },
        1: 10,
        "1": 11,
        "obj": obj,
    })
    x = UObject(d)


    assert x.a == x["a"] == 1
    assert x.b.c == x["b"]["c"] == 2
    assert x.b.d[0] == 3
    assert x.b.d[1] == 4
    assert x.b.e[0][0] == 6
    assert x.b.e[1][0] == 8
    assert x[1] == 10
    assert x["1"] == 11
    assert x[1] != x["1"]
    assert id(x) == id(x.b.self.b.self) == id(x.b.self)
    assert x.b.self.a == x.b.self.b.self.a == 1

    x.x = 12
    assert x.x == x["x"] == 12
    x.y = {"a":13,"b":[14,15]}
    assert x.y.a == 13
    assert x.y.b[0] == 14

def test02():
    x = Object({
        "a": {
            "b": 1,
            "c": [ 2, 3 ]
        },
        1: 6,
        2: [ 8, 9 ],
        3: 11,
    })
    y = Object({
        "a": {
            "b": 4,
            "c": [ 5 ]
        },
        1: 7,
        2: 10,
        3: [ 12 , 13 ],
    })
    z = {
        3: 14,
        2: 15,
        "a": {
            "b": 16,
            "c": 17,
        }
    }
    x.merge( y, z )
    assert 2 in x.a.c
    assert 3 in x.a.c
    assert 5 in x.a.c
    assert 1 in x.a.b
    assert 4 in x.a.b
    assert 8 in x[2]
    assert 9 in x[2]
    assert 10 in x[2]
    assert 11 in x[3]
    assert 12 in x[3]
    assert 13 in x[3]
    assert 14 in x[3]
    assert 15 in x[2]
    assert 16 in x.a.b
    assert 17 in x.a.c

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test01()
    test02()
```

Answer (score 4):

Wanted to upload my version of this little paradigm.

```
class Struct(dict):
  def __init__(self,data):
    for key, value in data.items():
      if isinstance(value, dict):
        setattr(self, key, Struct(value))
      else:   
        setattr(self, key, type(value).__init__(value))

      dict.__init__(self,data)
```

It preserves the attributes for the type that's imported into the class. My only concern would be overwriting methods from within the dictionary your parsing. But otherwise seems solid!

Comment: Although a nice idea, this doesn't seem to work for the OP's example, in fact it seems to modify the passed in dictionary! In fact, `df.a` doesn't even work.

Answer (score 3):

Here is another way to implement SilentGhost's original suggestion:

```
def dict2obj(d):
  if isinstance(d, dict):
    n = {}
    for item in d:
      if isinstance(d[item], dict):
        n[item] = dict2obj(d[item])
      elif isinstance(d[item], (list, tuple)):
        n[item] = [dict2obj(elem) for elem in d[item]]
      else:
        n[item] = d[item]
    return type('obj_from_dict', (object,), n)
  else:
    return d
```

Answer (score 3):

I stumbled upon the case I needed to recursively convert a list of dicts to list of objects, so based on Roberto's snippet here what did the work for me:

```
def dict2obj(d):
    if isinstance(d, dict):
        n = {}
        for item in d:
            if isinstance(d[item], dict):
                n[item] = dict2obj(d[item])
            elif isinstance(d[item], (list, tuple)):
                n[item] = [dict2obj(elem) for elem in d[item]]
            else:
                n[item] = d[item]
        return type('obj_from_dict', (object,), n)
    elif isinstance(d, (list, tuple,)):
        l = []
        for item in d:
            l.append(dict2obj(item))
        return l
    else:
        return d
```

Note that any tuple will be converted to its list equivalent, for obvious reasons.

Hope this helps someone as much as all your answers did for me, guys.

Answer (score 3):

What about just assigning your `dict` to the `__dict__` of an empty object?

```
class Object:
    """If your dict is "flat", this is a simple way to create an object from a dict

    >>> obj = Object()
    >>> obj.__dict__ = d
    >>> d.a
    1
    """
    pass
```

Of course this fails on your nested dict example unless you walk the dict recursively:

```
# For a nested dict, you need to recursively update __dict__
def dict2obj(d):
    """Convert a dict to an object

    >>> d = {'a': 1, 'b': {'c': 2}, 'd': ["hi", {'foo': "bar"}]}
    >>> obj = dict2obj(d)
    >>> obj.b.c
    2
    >>> obj.d
    ["hi", {'foo': "bar"}]
    """
    try:
        d = dict(d)
    except (TypeError, ValueError):
        return d
    obj = Object()
    for k, v in d.iteritems():
        obj.__dict__[k] = dict2obj(v)
    return obj
```

And your example list element was probably meant to be a `Mapping`, a list of (key, value) pairs like this:

```
>>> d = {'a': 1, 'b': {'c': 2}, 'd': [("hi", {'foo': "bar"})]}
>>> obj = dict2obj(d)
>>> obj.d.hi.foo
"bar"
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's another implementation:

```
class DictObj(object):
    def __init__(self, d):
        self.__dict__ = d

def dict_to_obj(d):
    if isinstance(d, (list, tuple)): return map(dict_to_obj, d)
    elif not isinstance(d, dict): return d
    return DictObj(dict((k, dict_to_obj(v)) for (k,v) in d.iteritems()))
```

[Edit] Missed bit about also handling dicts within lists, not just other dicts.  Added fix.

Comment: Note that setting __dict__ to the source dictionary means that any changes to attributes on the resulting object will also affect the dictionary that created the object, and vice-versa.  This may lead to unexpected results if the dictionary is used for something other than creating the object.

Comment: @Mark:  Actually, a new dictionary is being passed to DictObj every time, rather than just passing through the same dict object, so this won't actually occur.  It's neccessary to do this, as I need to translate the *values* within a dictionary as well, so it would be impossible to pass through the original dict object without mutating it myself.

Comment: There are quite a few answers to this, the accepted answer didn't look like it would be recursive or handle lists.  I read through them all and this one looked the simplest at first sight, I tested and it worked.  Great answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
class Struct(dict):
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        try:
            return self[name]
        except KeyError:
            raise AttributeError(name)

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        self[name] = value

    def copy(self):
        return Struct(dict.copy(self))
```

Usage:

```
points = Struct(x=1, y=2)
# Changing
points['x'] = 2
points.y = 1
# Accessing
points['x'], points.x, points.get('x') # 2 2 2
points['y'], points.y, points.get('y') # 1 1 1
# Accessing inexistent keys/attrs 
points['z'] # KeyError: z
points.z # AttributeError: z
# Copying
points_copy = points.copy()
points.x = 2
points_copy.x # 1
```

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
from functools import partial
d2o=partial(type, "d2o", ())
```

This can then be used like this:

```
>>> o=d2o({"a" : 5, "b" : 3})
>>> print o.a
5
>>> print o.b
3
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. The author want to convert nested dict. Try {'a': 1, 'b': {'b1': 2}} and you will get AttributeError

Answer (score 2):

I think a dict consists of number, string and dict is enough most time.
So I ignore the situation that tuples, lists and other types not appearing in the final dimension of a dict.

Considering inheritance, combined with recursion, it solves the print problem conveniently and also provides two ways to query a data,one way to edit a data.

See the example below, a dict that describes some information about students:

```
group=["class1","class2","class3","class4",]
rank=["rank1","rank2","rank3","rank4","rank5",]
data=["name","sex","height","weight","score"]

#build a dict based on the lists above
student_dic=dict([(g,dict([(r,dict([(d,'') for d in data])) for r in rank ]))for g in group])

#this is the solution
class dic2class(dict):
    def __init__(self, dic):
        for key,val in dic.items():
            self.__dict__[key]=self[key]=dic2class(val) if isinstance(val,dict) else val


student_class=dic2class(student_dic)

#one way to edit:
student_class.class1.rank1['sex']='male'
student_class.class1.rank1['name']='Nan Xiang'

#two ways to query:
print student_class.class1.rank1
print student_class.class1['rank1']
print '-'*50
for rank in student_class.class1:
    print getattr(student_class.class1,rank)
```

Results:

```
{'score': '', 'sex': 'male', 'name': 'Nan Xiang', 'weight': '', 'height': ''}
{'score': '', 'sex': 'male', 'name': 'Nan Xiang', 'weight': '', 'height': ''}
--------------------------------------------------
{'score': '', 'sex': '', 'name': '', 'weight': '', 'height': ''}
{'score': '', 'sex': '', 'name': '', 'weight': '', 'height': ''}
{'score': '', 'sex': 'male', 'name': 'Nan Xiang', 'weight': '', 'height': ''}
{'score': '', 'sex': '', 'name': '', 'weight': '', 'height': ''}
{'score': '', 'sex': '', 'name': '', 'weight': '', 'height': ''}
```

Answer (score 2):

```py
class Dict2Obj:
    def __init__(self, json_data):
        self.convert(json_data)

    def convert(self, json_data):
        if not isinstance(json_data, dict):
            return
        for key in json_data:
            if not isinstance(json_data[key], dict):
                self.__dict__.update({key: json_data[key]})
            else:
                self.__dict__.update({ key: Dict2Obj(json_data[key])})
```

I could not find the implementation of nested dictionary to object, so wrote one.

Usage:

```
>>> json_data = {"a": {"b": 2}, "c": 3}
>>> out_obj = Dict2Obj(json_data)
>>> out_obj.a
<Dict2Obj object at 0x7f3dc22c2d68>
>>> out_obj.a.b
2
>>> out_obj.a.c
3
```

Answer (score 2):

Looking for a simple wrapper class for `dict` enabling attribute-style key access/assignment (dot notation) I was not satisfied with the existing options for the reasons below.

`dataclasses`, `pydantic`, etc. are great but require a static definition of the content. Also, they cannot replace `dict` in code which relied on `dict` since they don't share the same methods and `__getitem__()` syntax is not supported.

Hence, I developed [MetaDict](https://github.com/LarsHill/metadict). It behaves exactly like `dict` but enables dot notation and IDE autocompletion (if the object is loaded in the RAM) without the shortcomings and potential namespace conflicts of other solutions. All features and usage examples can be found on GitHub (see link above).

Full disclosure: I am the author of [MetaDict](https://github.com/LarsHill/metadict).

Shortcomings/limitations I encountered when trying out other solutions:

- [Addict](https://github.com/mewwts/addict)

  - No key autocompletion in IDE
  - Nested key assignment cannot be turned off
  - Newly assigned `dict` objects are not converted to support attribute-style key access
  - Shadows inbuilt type `Dict`
- [Prodict](https://github.com/ramazanpolat/prodict)

  - No key autocompletion in IDE without defining a static schema (similar to `dataclass`)
  - No recursive conversion of `dict` objects when embedded in `list` or other inbuilt iterables
- [AttrDict](https://github.com/bcj/AttrDict)

  - No key autocompletion in IDE
  - Converts `list` objects to `tuple` behind the scenes
- [Munch](https://github.com/Infinidat/munch)

  - Inbuilt methods like `items()`, `update()`, etc. can be overwritten with `obj.items = [1, 2, 3]`
  - No recursive conversion of `dict` objects when embedded in `list` or other inbuilt iterables
- [EasyDict](https://github.com/makinacorpus/easydict)

  - Only strings are valid keys, but `dict` accepts all hashable objects as keys
  - Inbuilt methods like `items()`, `update()`, etc. can be overwritten with `obj.items = [1, 2, 3]`
  - Inbuilt methods don't behave as expected: `obj.pop('unknown_key', None)` raises an `AttributeError`

Note: I wrote a similar answer in this [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71017510/9463801), which is related.

Answer (score 1):

Building off my answer to "[python: How to add property to a class dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1325673/python-how-to-add-property-to-a-class-dynamically/1333275#1333275)":

```
class data(object):
    def __init__(self,*args,**argd):
        self.__dict__.update(dict(*args,**argd))

def makedata(d):
    d2 = {}
    for n in d:
        d2[n] = trydata(d[n])
    return data(d2)

def trydata(o):
    if isinstance(o,dict):
        return makedata(o)
    elif isinstance(o,list):
        return [trydata(i) for i in o]
    else:
        return o
```

You call `makedata` on the dictionary you want converted, or maybe `trydata` depending on what you expect as input, and it spits out a data object.

Notes:

- You can add elifs to `trydata` if you need more functionality.
- Obviously this won't work if you want `x.a = {}` or similar.
- If you want a readonly version, use the class data from [the original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1325673/python-how-to-add-property-to-a-class-dynamically/1333275#1333275).

Answer (score 1):

My dictionary is of this format:

```
addr_bk = {
    'person': [
        {'name': 'Andrew', 'id': 123, 'email': 'andrew@mailserver.com',
         'phone': [{'type': 2, 'number': '633311122'},
                   {'type': 0, 'number': '97788665'}]
        },
        {'name': 'Tom', 'id': 456,
         'phone': [{'type': 0, 'number': '91122334'}]}, 
        {'name': 'Jack', 'id': 7788, 'email': 'jack@gmail.com'}
    ]
}
```

As can be seen, I have **nested dictionaries** and **list of dicts**.
This is because the addr_bk was decoded from protocol buffer data that converted to a python dict using lwpb.codec. There are optional field (e.g. email => where key may be unavailable) and repeated field (e.g. phone => converted to list of dict).

I tried all the above proposed solutions. Some doesn't handle the nested dictionaries well. Others cannot print the object details easily.

Only the solution, dict2obj(dict) by Dawie Strauss, works best.

I have enhanced it a little to handle when the key cannot be found:

```
# Work the best, with nested dictionaries & lists! :)
# Able to print out all items.
class dict2obj_new(dict):
    def __init__(self, dict_):
        super(dict2obj_new, self).__init__(dict_)
        for key in self:
            item = self[key]
            if isinstance(item, list):
                for idx, it in enumerate(item):
                    if isinstance(it, dict):
                        item[idx] = dict2obj_new(it)
            elif isinstance(item, dict):
                self[key] = dict2obj_new(item)

    def __getattr__(self, key):
        # Enhanced to handle key not found.
        if self.has_key(key):
            return self[key]
        else:
            return None
```

Then, I tested it with:

```
# Testing...
ab = dict2obj_new(addr_bk)

for person in ab.person:
  print "Person ID:", person.id
  print "  Name:", person.name
  # Check if optional field is available before printing.
  if person.email:
    print "  E-mail address:", person.email

  # Check if optional field is available before printing.
  if person.phone:
    for phone_number in person.phone:
      if phone_number.type == codec.enums.PhoneType.MOBILE:
        print "  Mobile phone #:",
      elif phone_number.type == codec.enums.PhoneType.HOME:
        print "  Home phone #:",
      else:
        print "  Work phone #:",
      print phone_number.number
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a nested-ready version with namedtuple:

```
from collections import namedtuple

class Struct(object):
    def __new__(cls, data):
        if isinstance(data, dict):
            return namedtuple(
                'Struct', data.iterkeys()
            )(
                *(Struct(val) for val in data.values())
            )
        elif isinstance(data, (tuple, list, set, frozenset)):
            return type(data)(Struct(_) for _ in data)
        else:
            return data
```

=>

```
>>> d = {'a': 1, 'b': {'c': 2}, 'd': ["hi", {'foo': "bar"}]}
>>> s = Struct(d)
>>> s.d
['hi', Struct(foo='bar')]
>>> s.d[0]
'hi'
>>> s.d[1].foo
'bar'
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert `dict` to `object`

```py
from types import SimpleNamespace

def dict2obj(data):
    """将字典对象转换为可访问的对象属性"""
    if not isinstance(data, dict):
        raise ValueError('data must be dict object.')

    def _d2o(d):
        _d = {}
        for key, item in d.items():
            if isinstance(item, dict):
                _d[key] = _d2o(item)
            else:
                _d[key] = item
        return SimpleNamespace(**_d)

    return _d2o(data)
```

[Reference Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35920523)

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't satisfied with the marked and upvoted answers, so here is a *simple **and** general* solution for transforming JSON-style nested datastructures (made of dicts and lists) into hierachies of plain objects:

```
# tested in: Python 3.8
from collections import abc
from typings import Any, Iterable, Mapping, Union

class DataObject:
    def __repr__(self):
        return str({k: v for k, v in vars(self).items()})

def data_to_object(data: Union[Mapping[str, Any], Iterable]) -> object:
    """
    Example
    -------
    >>> data = {
    ...     "name": "Bob Howard",
    ...     "positions": [{"department": "ER", "manager_id": 13}],
    ... }
    ... data_to_object(data).positions[0].manager_id
    13
    """
    if isinstance(data, abc.Mapping):
        r = DataObject()
        for k, v in data.items():
            if type(v) is dict or type(v) is list:
                setattr(r, k, data_to_object(v))
            else:
                setattr(r, k, v)
        return r
    elif isinstance(data, abc.Iterable):
        return [data_to_object(e) for e in data]
    else:
        return data
```

Answer (score 1):

Building on what was done earlier by the accepted answer, if you would like to have it recursive.

```
class FullStruct:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        for key, value in kwargs.items():
            if isinstance(value, dict):
                f = FullStruct(**value)
                self.__dict__.update({key: f})
            else:
                self.__dict__.update({key: value})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use my way to handle it.

```
somedict= {"person": {"name": "daniel"}}

class convertor:
    def __init__(self, dic: dict) -> object:
        self.dict = dic

        def recursive_check(obj):
            for key, value in dic.items():
                if isinstance(value, dict):
                    value= convertor(value)
                setattr(obj, key, value)
        recursive_check(self)
my_object= convertor(somedict)

print(my_object.person.name)
```

Answer (score 1):

The following code from [here](https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/python-convert-nested-dictionary-to-object), works on nested dictionaries and IDEs such as VS Code are able to hint the existing attributes:

```py
class Struct:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        for key, value in kwargs.items():
            if isinstance(value, dict):
                self.__dict__[key] = Struct(**value)
            else:
                self.__dict__[key] = value


my_dict = {
    'name': 'bobbyhadz',
    'address': {
        'country': 'Country A',
        'city': 'City A',
        'codes': [1, 2, 3]
    },
}

obj = Struct(**my_dict)
```

If you want to see how to load a YAML file and covert it to a Python object, see this [gist](https://gist.github.com/Miladiouss/39ad8bbe1546e215307f8b7eef35fb31).

Comment: In general I like this solution because it's pretty concise. But, as with many of the other solutions, intermediate dictionaries become just an instance of the proxy (i.e. `my_dict.address` is no longer a dictionary, but an instance of `Struct`).

Answer (score 0):

I had some problems with `__getattr__` not being called so I constructed a new style class version:

```
class Struct(object):
    '''The recursive class for building and representing objects with.'''
    class NoneStruct(object):
        def __getattribute__(*args):
            return Struct.NoneStruct()

        def __eq__(self, obj):
            return obj == None

    def __init__(self, obj):
        for k, v in obj.iteritems():
            if isinstance(v, dict):
                setattr(self, k, Struct(v))
            else:
                setattr(self, k, v)

    def __getattribute__(*args):
        try:
            return object.__getattribute__(*args)
        except:            
            return Struct.NoneStruct()

    def __repr__(self):
        return '{%s}' % str(', '.join('%s : %s' % (k, repr(v)) for 
(k, v) in self.__dict__.iteritems()))
```

This version also has the addition of `NoneStruct` that is returned when an attribute is called that is not set. This allows for None testing to see if an attribute is present. Very usefull when the exact dict input is not known (settings etc.).

```
bla = Struct({'a':{'b':1}})
print(bla.a.b)
>> 1
print(bla.a.c == None)
>> True
```

Answer (score 0):

This is another, alternative, way to convert a list of dictionaries to an object:

```
def dict2object(in_dict):
    class Struct(object):
        def __init__(self, in_dict):
            for key, value in in_dict.items():
                if isinstance(value, (list, tuple)):
                    setattr(
                        self, key,
                        [Struct(sub_dict) if isinstance(sub_dict, dict)
                         else sub_dict for sub_dict in value])
                else:
                    setattr(
                        self, key,
                        Struct(value) if isinstance(value, dict)
                        else value)
    return [Struct(sub_dict) for sub_dict in in_dict] \
        if isinstance(in_dict, list) else Struct(in_dict)
```

Answer (score 0):

This little class never gives me any problem, just extend it and use the copy() method:

```
  import simplejson as json

  class BlindCopy(object):

    def copy(self, json_str):
        dic = json.loads(json_str)
        for k, v in dic.iteritems():
            if hasattr(self, k):
                setattr(self, k, v);
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated with recursive array expansion on @max-sirwa 's code

```
class Objectify:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        for key, value in kwargs.items():
            if isinstance(value, dict):
                f = Objectify(**value)
                self.__dict__.update({key: f})
            elif isinstance(value, list):
                t = []
                for i in value:
                    t.append(Objectify(**i)) if isinstance(i, dict) else t.append(i)
                self.__dict__.update({key: t})
            else:
                self.__dict__.update({key: value})
```

Answer (score 0):

The exact solution of the question can be achieved easily by PyPI package named [attrdict](https://pypi.org/project/attrdict/). The interesting fact about this package is that the dict can be accessed either as keys or as attributes.  Here is the solution -

```
from attrdict import AttrDict

d = {'a': 1, 'b': {'c': 2}, 'd': ["hi", {'foo': "bar"}]}

x = AttrDict(d)

print(x.a, x['a'])
print(x.b.c, x['b']['c'])
print(x.d[1].foo, x['d'][1]['foo'])
```

And output is as follows (obviously with no error) -

```
1 1
2 2
bar bar
```

**N.B.** It was first released in Feb 2, 2019 which means at the time of asking this question, this third party pypi package didn't exist. But if someone now wants to access dict value either by key or by attribute, this package surely can help as magic with only one line of code.