# Accessing dictionary with class attribute

Tags: python, dictionary

now I am working with python. So one question about dict ....
suppose I have a dict that

```
config = {'account_receivable': '4', 'account_payable': '5', 'account_cogs': '8', 'accoun
t_retained_earning': '9', 'account_income': '6', 'account_expense': '31', 'durat
ion': 2, 'financial_year_month': 9, 'financial_year_day': 15, 'account_cash': '3
', 'account_inventory': '2', 'account_accumulated_depriciation': '34', 'account_
depriciation_expense': '35', 'account_salary_expense': '30', 'account_payroll_pa
yable': '68', 'account_discount': '36', 'financial_year_close': '2008-08-08'}
```

if print --> config['account_receivable'] it will return its corresponding value that 4

but I want to access it by that way--> config.account_receivable and then it will return it corresponding value

how can I implement this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For that purpose, lo that many years ago, I invented the simple `Bunch` idiom; one simple way to implement `Bunch` is:

```
class Bunch(object):
  def __init__(self, adict):
    self.__dict__.update(adict)
```

If `config` is a dict, you can't use `config.account_receivable` -- that's absolutely impossible, because a dict doesn't **have** that attribute, period. However, you *can* wrap `config` into a `Bunch`:

```
cb = Bunch(config)
```

and then access `cb.config_account` to your heart's content!

**Edit**: if you want *attribute assignment* on the `Bunch` to also affect the original `dict` (`config` in this case), so that e.g. `cb.foo = 23` will do `config['foo'] = 23`, you need a slighly different implementation of `Bunch`:

```
class RwBunch(object):
  def __init__(self, adict):
    self.__dict__ = adict
```

Normally, the plain `Bunch` is preferred, exactly *because*, after instantiation, the `Bunch` instance and the `dict` it was "primed" from are entirely decoupled -- changes to either of them do not affect the other; and such decoupling, most often, is what's desired.

When you **do** want "coupling" effects, then `RwBunch` is the way to get them: with it, every attribute setting or deletion on the instance will intrinsically set or delete the item from the `dict`, and, vice versa, setting or deleting items from the `dict` will intrinsically set or delete attributes from the instance.

Answer (score 7):

You can do this with collections.namedtuple:

```
from collections import namedtuple
config_object = namedtuple('ConfigClass', config.keys())(*config.values())
print config_object.account_receivable
```

You can learn more about namedtuple here:

http://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.html

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [Convert Python dict to object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1305532/convert-python-dict-to-object).

Answer (score 3):

**You need to use one of Python's [special methods](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-attribute-access).**

```
class config(object):
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return self.data[name]


c = config(data_dict)
print c.account_discount
-> 36
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could do it with a bunch of objects.

```
class Config(object):
    pass

config = Config()
config.account_receivable = 4
print config.account_receivable
```

Obviously you can extend this class to do more for you.  e.g. define `__init__` so you can create it with arguments, and perhaps defaults.

You could possibly also use a [namedtuple](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html) ([python 2.4/2.5 link](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/500261/)).  This is a data structure specifically designed to hold structured records.

```
from collections import namedtuple
Config = namedtuple('Config', 'account_receivable account_payable')  # etc -- list all the fields
c = Config(account_receivable='4', account_payable='5')
print c.account_receivable
```

With namedtuples, you cannot change values once they have been set.

Answer (score 0):

You can subclass dict to return items from itself for undefined attributes:

```
class AttrAccessibleDict(dict):
    def __getattr__(self, key):
        try:
            return self[key]
        except KeyError:    
            return AttributeError(key)

config = AttrAccessibleDict(config)
print(config.account_receivable)
```

You might also want to override some other methods as well, such as `__setattr__`, `__delattr__`, `__str__`, `__repr__` and `copy`.