# What is a flexible, hybrid python collection object?

Tags: python, data-structures, autohotkey

As a way to get used to python, I am trying to translate some of my code to python from [Autohotkey_L](http://www.autohotkey.net/~Lexikos/AutoHotkey_L). 
I am immediately running into tons of choices for collection objects.  
Can you help me figure out a built in type or a 3rd party contributed type that has as much as possible,  the functionality of the AutoHotkey_L [object type](http://www.autohotkey.net/~Lexikos/AutoHotkey_L/docs/Objects.htm) and its [methods](http://www.autohotkey.net/~Lexikos/AutoHotkey_L/docs/objects/Object.htm).

AutoHotkey_L Objects have features of a python dict, list, and a class instance.

I understand that there are tradeoffs for space and speed, but I am just interested in functionality rather than optimization issues.

Comment: What features of `list` does it have?

Comment: object._insert and object._remove push and pop at the end of the object.  object items can be objects, and are mutable.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Don't write Python as `<another-language>`. Write Python as Python.

The data structure should be chosen just to have the minimal ability you need to use.

- `list` — an *ordered* sequence of elements, with 1 flexible end.
- `collections.deque` — an *ordered* sequence of elements, with 2 flexible ends (e.g. a queue).
- `set` / `frozenset` — an *unordered* sequence of *unique* elements.
- `collections.Counter` — an *unordered* sequence of *non-unique* elements.
- `dict` — an *unordered* key-value relationship.
- `collections.OrderedDict` — an *ordered* key-value relationship.
- `bytes` / `bytearray` — a list of bytes.
- `array.array` — a homogeneous list of primitive types.

Looking at the interface of Object,

- `dict` would be the most suitable for finding a value by key
- `collections.OrderedDict` would be the most suitable for the push/pop stuff.

when you need MinIndex / MaxIndex, where a *sorted* key-value relationship (e.g. red black tree) is required. There's no such type in the standard library, but there are [3rd party implementations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2298165/pythons-standard-library-is-there-a-module-for-balanced-binary-tree).

Answer (score 1):

It would be impossible to recommend a particular class without knowing how you intend on using it. If you are using this particular object as an ordered sequence where elements can be repeated, then you should use a list; if you are looking up values by their key, then use a dictionary. You will get very different algorithmic runtime complexity with the different data types. It really does not take that much time to determine when to use which type.... I suggest you give it some further consideration.

If you really can't decide, though, here is a possibility:

```
class AutoHotKeyObject(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.list_value = []
        self.dict_value = {}
    def getDict(self):
        return self.dict_value
    def getList(self):
        return self.list_value
```

With the above, you could use both the list and dictionary features, like so:

```
obj = AutoHotKeyObject()
obj.getList().append(1)
obj.getList().append(2)
obj.getList().append(3)
print obj.getList() # Prints [1, 2, 3]
obj.getDict()['a'] = 1
obj.getDict()['b'] = 2
print obj.getDict() # Prints {'a':1, 'b':2}
```

Comment: there are some interesting ideas here as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1338714/accesing-dictionary-with-class-atribute.   I'd also like to be able to apply list processing to the dict / class "bunch" they describe.