# Data Classes vs typing.NamedTuple primary use cases

Tags: python, namedtuple, pep, python-3.7, python-dataclasses

### Long story short

[PEP-557](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0557/) introduced data classes into Python standard library, that basically can fill the same role as `collections.namedtuple` and `typing.NamedTuple`. And now I'm wondering how to separate the use cases in which namedtuple is still a better solution.

### Data classes advantages over NamedTuple

Of course, all the credit goes to `dataclass` if we need:

- mutable objects
- inheritance support
- `property` decorators, manageable attributes
- generated method definitions out of the box or customizable method definitions

Data classes advantages are briefly explained in the same PEP: [Why not just use namedtuple](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0557/#why-not-just-use-namedtuple).

### Q: In which cases namedtuple is still a better choice?

But how about an opposite question for namedtuples: why not just use dataclass?
I guess probably namedtuple is better from the performance standpoint but found no confirmation on that yet.

### Example

Let's consider the following situation:

We are going to store pages dimensions in a small container with statically defined fields, type hinting and named access. No further hashing, comparing and so on are needed.

**NamedTuple approach:**

```
from typing import NamedTuple

PageDimensions = NamedTuple("PageDimensions", [('width', int), ('height', int)])
```

**DataClass approach:**

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class PageDimensions:
    width: int
    height: int
```

Which solution is preferable and why?

P.S. the question isn't a duplicate of [that one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47955263) in any way, because here I'm asking about **the cases** in which namedtuple is better, not about **the difference** (I've checked docs and sources before asking)

Comment: I've seen that question, but there are no answer about the main point: in which cases namedtuples are still better to use?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3357581/using-python-class-as-a-data-container

Comment: Note that using a list of `NamedTuple`s as an input for `np.array` will "just work" because (as mentioned in the accepted answer) `NamedTuple` inherits from `tuple`. Numpy does not handle dataclasses as smoothly (treating them as having dtype `object`).

Comment: TLDR for beginners: choose data classes.

Comment: It's worth noting that [NamedTuples have issues with subclassing](https://github.com/python/typing/issues/427).

Answer (score 191, accepted):

It depends on your needs. Each of them has own benefits.

Here is a good explanation of Dataclasses on PyCon 2018 [Raymond Hettinger - Dataclasses: The code generator to end all code generators](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T-TwcmT6Rcw&t=1390)

In **`Dataclass` all implementation is written in Python**, whereas in `NamedTuple`, all of these behaviors come for free because `NamedTuple` inherits from `tuple`. And because the **`tuple` structure is written in C**, standard methods are faster in `NamedTuple` (hash, comparing and etc).

Note also that **`Dataclass` is based on `dict`** whereas **`NamedTuple` is based on `tuple`**. Thus, you have advantages and disadvantages of using these structures. For example, space usage is less with a `NamedTuple`, but time access is faster with a `Dataclass`.

Please, see my experiment:

```
In [33]: a = PageDimensionsDC(width=10, height=10)

In [34]: sys.getsizeof(a) + sys.getsizeof(vars(a))
Out[34]: 168

In [35]: %timeit a.width
43.2 ns ± 1.05 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)

In [36]: a = PageDimensionsNT(width=10, height=10)

In [37]: sys.getsizeof(a)
Out[37]: 64

In [38]: %timeit a.width
63.6 ns ± 1.33 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000000 loops each)
```

But with increasing the number of attributes of `NamedTuple` access time remains the same small, because for each attribute it creates a property with the name of the attribute. For example, for our case the part of the namespace of the new class will look like:

```
from operator import itemgetter

class_namespace = {
...
    'width': property(itemgetter(0, doc="Alias for field number 0")),
    'height': property(itemgetter(0, doc="Alias for field number 1"))**
}
```

> In which cases namedtuple is still a better choice?

When your data structure needs to/can be **immutable, hashable, iterable, unpackable, comparable then you can use `NamedTuple`**. If you need something **more complicated, for example, a possibility of inheritance** for your data structure then use `Dataclass`.

Comment: I agree with this answer. In my case I use a NamedTuple via typing if possible because it can be unpacked and spread. However there are many cases when I need a dataclass, commonly because of inheritance or custom init.

Comment: i find it interesting that both `dataclasses.Dataclass` and `collections.namedtuple` are both just code generators. facinating. in the case of `collections.namedtuple` it has a huge template string literal that gets `exec`. i thought they were going to create all of this programmatically somehow. but code generation then exec makes sense.

Comment: FWIW, dataclasses can also be immutable, hashable, iterable and comparable. The `dataclass()` decorator accepts a kwarg `frozen=True`.

Comment: In dataclasses you can specify the types of the attributes.

Comment: why dict is less time than tuple at accessing attributes ?

Comment: @VaNa in `typing.NamedTuple` you can (and must) specify the types of the attributes.

Comment: The NamedTuple has to do a dict fetch on the class to find the property then a tuple lookup.

Comment: dataclass concept is so useful and convenient that it should become a keyword in python. . . . ->  https://youtube.com/live/0lCIkY32AdI?feature=share

Answer (score 45):

In programming in general, anything that CAN be immutable SHOULD be immutable. We gain two things:

1. Easier to read the program- we don't need to worry about values changing, once it's instantiated, it'll never change (namedtuple)
2. Less chance for weird bugs

That's why, if the data is immutable, you should use a named tuple instead of a dataclass

I wrote it in the comment, but I'll mention it here:
You're definitely right that there is an overlap, especially with `frozen=True` in dataclasses- but there are still features such as unpacking belonging to namedtuples, and it always being immutable- I doubt they'll remove namedtuples as such

Comment: Why not a dataclass with `@dataclass(frozen=True)`?

Comment: Another advantage is unpacking in namedtuples- e.g. if I have a Point(x, y),
I can unpack it `x, y = point`-

Comment: I want to make it clear though that you're right in a sense- namedtuples were created before python3, and there's obviously a bit of an overlap here. But because it's not an exact replacement (unpacking, namedtuples always being immutable), they probably won't remove namedtuples

Comment: @maor10 thanks for the answer, unpacking is really the only advantage I see yet. As mentioned above, the dataclass can be immutable.

Comment: I think you may rewrite the answer a little in order to make it clear for the others and accept it. It seems that immutability itself is NOT the thing here, mainly it's about unpacking.

Answer (score 39):

I had this same question, so ran a few tests and documented them here: https://shayallenhill.com/python-struct-options/

Summary:

- **NamedTuple is better for unpacking, exploding, and size.**
- **DataClass is faster and more flexible.**
- The differences aren't tremendous, and I wouldn't refactor stable code to move from one to another.
- NamedTuple is also great for soft typing when you'd like to be able to pass a tuple instead.

To do this, define a type inheriting from it...

```
from typing import NamedTuple

class CircleArg(NamedTuple):
    x: float
    y: float
    radius: float
```

...then unpack it inside your functions. Don't use the `.attributes`, and you'll have a nice "type hint" without any PITA for the caller.

```
*focus, radius = circle_arg_instance  # or tuple
```

Comment: "I wouldn't refactor stable code to move from one to another." - A Wise Developer

Comment: what is the purpose of the  `or tuple` parameter syntax ?

Comment: @WestCoastProjects, just poor formatting on my part. Updated now. The line was just trying to get across that you can enter either a) an instance of the CircleArg class or b) a plain 3-tuple ... on the right-hand side of the =.

Comment: NamedTuple is much faster than DataClass on every metric other than attribute access, where the difference is relatively small. When it comes to instance creation, sorting, and hashing, NamedTuple is by far the best choice if performance is a major concern.

Answer (score 38):

I didn't see any of the other answers mention it, but in my opinion one of the most important differences is to do with how equality and comparison work. When you compare named tuples, the names are ignored: two named tuples are equal if they contain the same values in the same order, even if they have different class names or field names:

```
>>> from collections import namedtuple
>>> A = namedtuple('A', ())
>>> B = namedtuple('B', ())
>>> a = A()
>>> b = B()
>>> a == b
True
```

Dataclasse instances, on the other hand, will only be considered equal if they are of the same type. I pretty much always want the latter behaviour: I expect things of different types to be distinct.

Answer (score 14):

Another important limitation to `NamedTuple` is that it cannot be generic:

```
import typing as t
T=t.TypeVar('T')
class C(t.Generic[T], t.NamedTuple): ...

TypeError: Multiple inheritance with NamedTuple is not supported
```

Comment: This is actually a bug. It should be [fixed in Python 3.11](https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/92027).

Answer (score 8):

One usecase for me is frameworks that do not support `dataclasses`. In particular, [TensorFlow](https://www.tensorflow.org/). There, a `tf.function` can work with a `typing.NamedTuple` but not with a `dataclass`.

```
class MyFancyData(typing.NamedTuple):
  some_tensor: tf.Tensor
  some_other_stuf: ...

@tf.function
def train_step(self, my_fancy_data: MyFancyData):
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

There is another small difference between them not mentioned so far.
The attributes of named tuples can be accessed by their names and indexes, while the attributes of data classes only by their attribute names. I ran into this difference when sorting list of objects.

For named tuples, we can use both the `itemgetter` and `attrgetter` helper functions. For data classes, we can use only the `attrgetter` function.

```py
#!/usr/bin/python

from typing import NamedTuple
from operator import itemgetter, attrgetter
# from dataclasses import dataclass

# @dataclass(frozen=True)
# class City:
#     cid: int
#     name: str
#     population: int

class City(NamedTuple):
    cid: int
    name: str
    population: int

c1 = City(1, 'Bratislava', 432000)
c2 = City(2, 'Budapest', 1759000)
c3 = City(3, 'Prague', 1280000)
c4 = City(4, 'Warsaw', 1748000)
c5 = City(5, 'Los Angeles', 3971000)
c6 = City(6, 'Edinburgh', 464000)
c7 = City(7, 'Berlin', 3671000)

cities = [c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6, c7]

sorted_cities = sorted(cities, key=attrgetter('name'))

for city in sorted_cities:
    print(city)

print('---------------------')

sorted_cities = sorted(cities, key=itemgetter(2))

for city in sorted_cities:
    print(city)
```