# Can tensorflow's tf.function be used with methods of dataclasses?

Tags: python, tensorflow, python-dataclasses

Can methods of `dataclass`es be decorated with `@tf.function`? A straight-forward test

```
@dataclass
class Doubler:
    @tf.function
    def double(a):
        return a*2
```

gives an error

```
d = Doubler()
d.double(2)
```

saying that `Doubler` is not hashable (`TypeError: unhashable type: 'Doubler'`), which I believe is because hashing is disabled by default for dataclasses. Is this a general limitation or can it be made to work? I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68924806/143931) that seems to indicate that it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

I think the official recommendation from Tensorflow is to use `tf.experimental.ExtensionType`:

```
import tensorflow as tf

class Doubler(tf.experimental.ExtensionType):
    @tf.function
    def double(self, a):
        return a*2
d = Doubler()
d.double(2)
```

According to the [docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/extension_type#extension_types_2):

> The tf.experimental.ExtensionType base class works similarly to
> typing.NamedTuple and @dataclasses.dataclass from the standard Python
> library. In particular, it automatically adds a constructor and
> special methods (such as **repr** and **eq**) based on the field type
> annotations.

If you read further down in the docs, you will see what features are provided by default.