# Python: type annotate a function return value that returns a class defined in that function

Tags: python, python-3.7, type-annotation, python-3.12

I'm wondering what the proper way to type annotate a return value of a function or method where a class is defined inside of that function.

For example:

```py
from typing import List
from dataclasses import dataclass

def get_users() -> List['ReturnUser']:

    @dataclass
    class ReturnUser:
       first_name: str
       last_name: str

    return [
        ReturnUser("John", "Doe"), 
        ReturnUser("Jane", "Doe")]
```

... the ReturnUser dataclass is only relevant within the scope of the function. (I don't care about the object outside of the `get_users()` function other than that I can access its properties in the calling code).

However, Pylance shows the return value annotation `List['ReturnUser']` as a type error. My environment is unfortunately Python 3.7, but also curious about if newer approaches exist in newer Python versions?

How do I annotate a return value that doesn't yet exist like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not only does `ReturnUser` not exist *yet*, but it's a different class every time. We can verify this easily.

```
>>> a = get_users()
>>> b = get_users()
>>> type(a[0]) is type(b[0])
False
```

So my first advice is to not do this. Make a module-level class and prefix it with an underscore to indicate that it's private. There are very, very, *very* few good reasons to define a `class` inside of a `def` in Python.

That being said, let's suppose this truly is the only way. Let's suppose there's some design constraint not being shown here, and you can't get rid of that class pattern. As I said, `ReturnUser` is *not* a correct return type, since the function returns a value of a different (unrelated) class every time. If you want the return type of your function to be "something with a `first_name` and `last_name` field", we can use [`Protocol`](https://peps.python.org/pep-0544/) to do that.

```
class _ReturnUserLike(Protocol):
    first_name: str
    last_name: str

def get_users() -> List[_ReturnUserLike]:
    # ... Same class body, including the local class ...
```

Now the only type-level guarantee to your callers is that you have properties `first_name` and `last_name` which are strings. A `Protocol` is a structural type, which means anything that looks like that class counts as an instance for the purposes of type-checking.

Comment: Thank you for your reply and advice on this. My thinking with the dataclass return value is that it would be a short-lived "holder" for return data and would be a little more expressive and better documented than returning that data in a tuple or dict. However, I see your point with defining it as a global object instead, as otherwise it messes with the definition of equality and probably is just confusing to callers of that function (since they don't know what that object is). Thanks also for the example using Protocol; I'll read about that as well.

Comment: @JoeJ: Since you've mentioned considering tuples, maybe [named tuples](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) would work better than a data class for your use case.  See [Data Classes vs typing.NamedTuple primary use cases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51671699/data-classes-vs-typing-namedtuple-primary-use-cases)

Comment: You're quite welcome! And with the added information, I agree with Nikolaj; I've been in that situation before and a `NamedTuple` is a great middle ground: It's got named fields for organization and debugging purposes but can be destructured at the call site, just like a tuple.