# Python: Data Object or class

Tags: python, class, dictionary

I enjoy all the python libraries for scraping websites and I am experimenting with BeautifulSoup and IMDB just for fun.

As I come from Java, I have some Java-practices incorporated into my programming styles. I am trying to get the info of a certain movie, I can either create a Movie class or just use a dictionary with keys for the attributes.

My question is, should I just use dictionaries when a class will only contain data and perhaps almost no behaviour? In other languages creating a type will help you enforce certain restrictions and because of type checks the IDE will help you program, this is not always the case in python, so what should I do?

Should I resort to creating a class only when there's both, behaviour and data? Or create a movie class even though it'll probably be just a data container?

This all depends on your model, in this particular case either one is fine but I'm wondering about what's a good practice.

Comment: Adding info to your question: A dictionary is mutable and is a container type which can store any number of python objects or other container type. You are trying to compare a container and an object! What's better? I don't know too.

Comment: Similar to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4045161/python-should-i-use-a-class-or-dictionary

Answer (score 6):

It's fine to use a class just to store attributes. You may also wish to use a [namedtuple](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#namedtuple-factory-function-for-tuples-with-named-fields) instead

The main differences between dict and class are the way you access the attributes `[]` vs `.` and inheritence.

`instance.__dict__` is just a `dict` after all

You can even just use a single class for all of those types of objects if you wish

```
class Bunch:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.__dict__.update(kwargs)

movie = Bunch(title='foo', director='bar', ...)
```

Comment: On the other hand, it's also fine (and much easier for everyone involved) to use existing data structures to hold data whenever appropriate. Also, `namedtuple` is awesome but some use cases don't get along with its immutability.

Answer (score 0):

In your case you could use a class that inherits from `dict` (e.g `class MyClass(dict)`) so that you can define custom behavior to your dict-like class or use [UserDict](http://docs.python.org/library/userdict.html#module-UserDict).

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you really mean for "perhaps almost no behaviour", if `dict` already provides what you need stay with it. Otherwise consider to subclass `dict` adding your specific behaviour. Since Python 2.2 [it is possible](http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.2/descrintro/#subclassing). Using `UserDict` is an older approach to the problem.

You could also use a plain dictionary and implement the behaviour externally via some function. I use this approach for prototyping, and eventually refactor the code later to make it Object Oriented (generally more scalable).

You can see what a dictionary offers typing this at the interpreter:

```
>>> help({})
```

or [referring to the docs](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries).

Answer (score -3):

I would stick to KISS (Keep it simple stupid). If you only want to store values you are better off with a dictionary, because you can dynamically add values at runtime. WRONG:(But you can not add new filds to a class at runtime.)

So classes are useful if they provide state and behaviour.

EDIT: You can add fields to classes in python.

Comment: This is Python. You _can_ add to classes at runtime

Comment: exactly, it's precisely because this is python that I am asking.

Comment: Oh, I didn´t know that, sorry.