# access dict with key as method (getter & setter) invocation syntax

Tags: python, dictionary, setter, getter

In Python,

Is there a way to access dict similar the way a method is invoked on an object. Scenario is, I thought to create a class with just attributes, there are no methods. And I came across few discussion on this scenario [Python: Should I use a class or dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4045161/python-should-i-use-a-class-or-dictionary). I've decided to go for `dict` instead of `class`.

No I would just like to understand, is there a way I can access elements of dict similar to method invocation on a object?

```
mydict = {'a': 100, 'b': 20.5, 'c': 'Hello'}
```

Instead of,

```
mydict['a']
mydict['a'] = 200
```

Something like,

```
mydict.a
mydict.a = 200
```

[namedtuple](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) does solve one part, that is, I can initialize and read. But not to be intended to set/write values.

Comment: [AttrDict](https://github.com/bcj/AttrDict) does exactly what you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is easily done by implementing `__getattr__` and `__setattr__` in a subclass:

```
class MyDict(dict):
    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        return self[attr]
    def __setattr__(self, attr, value):
        self[attr] = value
```

Comment: @PaulPanzer Well yes. You _could_ get around that (with `__getattribute__`), but I don't think it's worth the effort.