# Complex transforming nested dictionaries into objects in python

Tags: python

It hasn't been long since I started learning python, but I really want to dig in it. And dig it hard. So here is a task I've been studying for a while but haven't cracked yet:
I am given a mixed combination of nested dictionaries and lists (let's call it "**combination**"), and I need to implement *function* that will allow accessing nested elements as object attributes, also somehow treating **combination** elements as iterable. This should look something like this:

```
combination = {
'item1': 3.14,
'item2': 42,
'items': [
         'text text text',
         {
             'field1': 'a',
             'field2': 'b',
         },
         {
             'field1': 'c',
             'field2': 'd',
         },
         ]
}

def function(combination):
    ...
```

so that
`list(function(combination).items.field1)`
will give: `['a', 'c']`, and
`list(function(combination).item1)` will give: `[3.14]`.
**Edit** As mentioned by @FM, I missed description of handling non-dict elements:
`list(function(combination).items[0])` >>> `['text text text']`

---

I tried implementing a class (kudos to [Marc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1305532/convert-python-dict-to-object/1305663#1305663)) to help me:

```
class Struct:
    def __init__(self, **entries): 
        self.__dict__.update(entries)
```

and then using it in the *function* like `return Struct(**combination)`
While being very nifty, it is only the first step to the desired result.
But as the next step needs to go deeper, it overwhelms me and I can't make it on myself.
Therefore, I kindly ask for your help.

Michael.

Comment: +1 for an interesting question. But your desired to jump directly from a key like `items` to a key like `field1` seems to be in tension with a general approach that preserves all information. Is the latter an important goal for you? More specifically, how do you envision accessing the non-dict elements stored under `items` (`'text text text'`)?

Comment: @FM _combination_ is not based on a specific real information scheme, so any logical inconsistencies do not mean a lot (if I understood you correctly). Accessing non-dict elements is an important point. I think `result.items` should support slicing and such. I'll edit question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about:

```
class ComboParser(object):
    def __init__(self,data):
        self.data=data
    def __getattr__(self,key):
        try:
            return ComboParser(self.data[key])
        except TypeError:
            result=[]
            for item in self.data:
                if key in item:
                    try:
                        result.append(item[key])
                    except TypeError: pass
            return ComboParser(result)
    def __getitem__(self,key):
        return ComboParser(self.data[key])
    def __iter__(self):
        if isinstance(self.data,basestring):
            # self.data might be a str or unicode object
            yield self.data
        else:
            # self.data might be a list or tuple
            try:
                for item in self.data:
                    yield item
            except TypeError:
                # self.data might be an int or float
                yield self.data
    def __length_hint__(self):
        return len(self.data)
```

which yields:

```
combination = {
    'item1': 3.14,
    'item2': 42,
    'items': [
        'text text text',
        {
            'field1': 'a',
            'field2': 'b',
            },
        {
            'field1': 'c',
            'field2': 'd',
            },
        {
            'field1': 'e',
            'field3': 'f',
            },        
        ]
    }
print(list(ComboParser(combination).item1))
# [3.1400000000000001]
print(list(ComboParser(combination).items))
# ['text text text', {'field2': 'b', 'field1': 'a'}, {'field2': 'd', 'field1': 'c'}, {'field3': 'f', 'field1': 'e'}]
print(list(ComboParser(combination).items[0]))
# ['text text text']
print(list(ComboParser(combination).items.field1))
# ['a', 'c', 'e']
```

Comment: +1: Wow, very clever recursive use of Martelli's (and Doug Hudgeon's) `Bunch` collection/container class. Minor cosmetic suggestion though, I'd make `convert()` a `@classmethod` which would require the call to it to become `result=Bunch.convert(combination)` -- to make things just a little more explicit.

Comment: How can I make `result.items` iterable? I feel that it must be simple, but I'm still not so good at this.

Comment: Also items `'text text text'` becomes unavailable after _merge_. I am sorry that I forgot to mention importance of non-dict accessibility from start (edited later). **In general**, do you think it is possible to make _function_ act like a generator? I mean to generate those output results on-the-fly when asked for them, not pre-evaluate. Would that be _pythonic_?

Comment: Thank you very much! (Beating recursion like a boss)

Answer (score 3):

For example:

```
class Struct:
    def __init__(self, **entries):
        for key, value in entries.items():
            value2 = (Struct(**value) if isinstance(value, dict) else value)
            self.__dict__[key] = value2

entries = {
    "a": 1,
    "b": {
        "c": {
            "d": 2
        }
    }
}

obj = Struct(**entries)
print(obj.a) #1
print(obj.b.c.d) #2
```

Answer (score 1):

I think there are basically two options you could pursue here:

1. Make `function` convert the nested data structure into a series of objects linked together that implement the protocols for supporting `list()` and `dict()` (the objects must implement a number of functions, including at least `__iter__`, `__len__`, `__getitem__`, etc). To create the objects, you need to either define classes that implement these behaviors, and assemble them recursively, or create classes on the fly using `type()`.
2. Make `function` return a class that proxies access to the underlying data structure. To implement a class that allows member attribute access for not-actually-members (i.e. doing `function(combination).items`), you override `__getattr__`. You won't be able to access the "full dotted path" so to speak in any single invocation of this function, so it will have to operate recursively and return additional instances at each level of the dotted path. I believe this approach will be simpler than the first.

Answer (score 1):

What you probably need to do then is look at each item that you assign to your object's `__dict__` to see if it is itself a dict or iterable.

```
import types
class Struct:
    def __init__(self, **entries):
        self.__dict__.update(entries)
        for k,v in self.__dict__.items():
            if type(v) == types.DictType:
                setattr(self, k, Struct(**v))
```

so that you're using a recursive arrangement.  Looks something like this:

```
>>> b = Struct(a=1, b={'a':1})
>>> b.b.a
1
```