# What is the Python counterpart to an Ada record / C++ struct type?

Tags: c++, python, record, ada

Suppose I am recording data and want to associate some number of data elements, such that each recorded set **always** has a fixed composition, i.e. no missing fields.

Most of my experience as a programmer is with Ada or C/C++ variants.  In Ada, I would use a record type and aggregate assignment, so that when the record type was updated with new fields, anyone using the record would be notified by the compiler.  In C++, chances are I would use a storage class and constructor to do something similar.

What is the appropriate way to handle a similar situation in Python?  Is this a case where classes are the proper answer, or is there a lighter weight analog to the Ada record?

An additional thought, both Ada records and C++ constructors allow for default initialization values.  Is there a Python solution to the above question which provides that capability as well?

Comment: AFAIK, Python is too dynamic to let you enforce a structure on all objects in such a way that you can't add or remove fields, but I've been wrong a lot about Python lately.

Comment: @zneak: You can use [`__slots__`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#slots) to enforce that arbitrary attributes can't be created on an object, but it should be avoided.

Comment: @zneak: That was my assumption as I started working with the language, but so far I've found it flexible enough to provide a substantial amount of structure.  Ironically.

Comment: take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1305532/convert-python-dict-to-object/1305663#1305663

Comment: counterpart, not corollary. A corollary is a statement that follows from a previous statement, something extra that is trivially seen to be true once you have proven a theorem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A [namedtuple](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html?highlight=namedtuple#namedtuple-factory-function-for-tuples-with-named-fields) (from the collections library) may suit your purposes. It is basically a tuple which allows reference to fields by name as well as index position. So it's a fixed structure of ordered named fields. It's also lightweight in that it uses `slots` to define field names thus eliminating the need to carry a dictionary in every instance.

A typical use case is to define a point:

```
from collections import namedtuple
Point = namedtuple("Point", "x y")
p1 = Point(x=11, y=22)
```

It's main drawback is that, being a tuple, it is immutable. But there is a method, `replace` which allows you to replace one or more fields with new values, but a new instance is created in the process.

There is also a mutable version of namedtuple available at ActiveState Python Recipes 576555 called [records](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576555/) which permits direct field changes. I've used it and can vouch that it works well.

Answer (score 3):

A dictionary is the classical way to do this in Python. It can't enforce that a value must exist though, and doesn't do initial values.

```
config = {'maxusers': 20, 'port': 2345, 'quota': 20480000}
```

[`collections.namedtuple()`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) is another option in versions of Python that support it.

Comment: I've used a dictionary for similar things before, though usually for paired values.  It has the added benefit of limiting duplicate keys.

Comment: +1: A class is a dict plus a bunch of stuff that you don't need.  Another way to have default values is to just have a prototypical dict that you copy before setting your values.