# How to define a dictionary with constraints? (validate a dictionary)

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to define a nested dictionary with a set of keys such that

1. new keys can not be added i.e the structure of the dictionary remains the same
2. the keys cannot be empty i.e. the keys of `summary` should not be null similarly the list of items stored in `items` should not be null

the dictionary I want to make:

```
{
  summary: {
    amount:
    date:
    phone_number:
  }

  # items is a list of dictionary there is no limit in the number of items but 
  # there has to be at least one item present
  # each key in item should have a value

  items: [   
    {
      id:
      desc:
      quantity:
      total:  
    },
    {
      id:
      desc:
      quantity:
      total:  
    },
    {
      id:
      desc:
      quantity:
      total:  
    }
  ]
}
```

Can you guys please give me any idea what approach I should take to achieve this and how I would do it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the Python counterpart to an Ada record / C++ struct type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6288285/what-is-the-python-counterpart-to-an-ada-record-c-struct-type)

Comment: why not use a class?

Comment: ... or a database?

Comment: i dont want to save the dict values I just have to validate it that is why I am not using database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you describe sounds like a perfect use case for the [schema](https://pypi.org/project/schema/) package. Motivating use from the readme:

```py
>>> from schema import Schema, And, Use, Optional, SchemaError

>>> schema = Schema([{'name': And(str, len),
...                   'age':  And(Use(int), lambda n: 18 <= n <= 99),
...                   Optional('gender'): And(str, Use(str.lower),
...                                           lambda s: s in ('squid', 'kid'))}])

>>> data = [{'name': 'Sue', 'age': '28', 'gender': 'Squid'},
...         {'name': 'Sam', 'age': '42'},
...         {'name': 'Sacha', 'age': '20', 'gender': 'KID'}]

>>> validated = schema.validate(data)

>>> assert validated == [{'name': 'Sue', 'age': 28, 'gender': 'squid'},
...                      {'name': 'Sam', 'age': 42},
...                      {'name': 'Sacha', 'age' : 20, 'gender': 'kid'}]
```

Comment: Don't want to recommend anything, but `schema` is currently classified on PyPi as being in the "alpha" stage.  Similar `voluptuous` is classified as "stable", but it is developed only by contributors, not the original author.

Comment: This "alpha" stage is definitely too conservative. The package has released versions since the year 2012, and has stabilized quite a bit during the past 5 years. While the "1.0.0" release is still outstanding, I would consider it mature enough for "general consumpation" - your mileage may vary.