# Is there a python json library can convert json to model objects, similar to google-gson?

Tags: python, json

The standard python json module only can convert json string to dict structures.

But I prefer to convert json to a model object strutures with their "parent-child" relationship.

I use google-gson in Android apps but don't know which python library could do this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could let the json module construct a dict and then use an [`object_hook`](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html#module-json) to [transform the dict into an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1305532/convert-python-dict-to-object), something like this:

```
>>> import json
>>>
>>> class Person(object):
...     firstName = ""
...     lastName = ""
...
>>>
>>> def as_person(d):
...     p = Person()
...     p.__dict__.update(d)
...     return p
...
>>>
>>> s = '{ "firstName" : "John", "lastName" : "Smith" }'
>>> o = json.loads(s, object_hook=as_person)
>>>
>>> type(o)
<class '__main__.Person'>
>>>
>>> o.firstName
u'John'
>>>
>>> o.lastName
u'Smith'
>>>
```

Comment: Tt works with object_hook. Thanks @Bogdan.

Comment: how about model in model

Comment: It will not work if the object has datetime.

Answer (score 1):

You could write your own serializer to make it work with json, but why not use [`pyyaml`](http://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAML) which supports it out of the box:

```
>>> import yaml
>>> class Foo:
...    def bar(self):
...       print 'Hello I am bar'
...    def zoo(self,i):
...       self.i = i
...       print "Eye is ",i
... 
>>> f = Foo()
>>> f.zoo(2)
Eye is  2
>>> s = yaml.dump(f)
>>> f2 = yaml.load(s)
>>> f2.zoo(3)
Eye is  3
>>> s
'!!python/object:__main__.Foo {i: 2}\n'
>>> f2 = yaml.load(s)
>>> f2.i
2
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but for the reason of backward compatibility I need to use JSON.

Comment: http://yamltojson.com/

Answer (score 0):

In 2018 it can be done with [cattrs](https://github.com/Tinche/cattrs), utilizing static typing with [attrs](https://github.com/python-attrs/attrs) and [mypy](http://mypy-lang.org/)