# how to convert json to model in python3

Tags: python, json

i am trying convert `json` string to `model`

then it is easy to get value with `.`

i have checked  [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11590190/is-there-a-python-json-library-can-convert-json-to-model-objects-similar-to-goo)

but different, my json sting looks like,

```
{
   "id":"123",
   "name":"name",
   "key":{
      "id":"345",
      "des":"des"
    },
}
```

i prefer to use 2 class like,

```
class A:
    id = ''
    name = ''
    key = new B()


class B:
    id = ''
    des = ''
```

Answer (score 2):

There are few libraries that might help:

- [marshmallow](http://marshmallow.readthedocs.io/) is nice
- [colander](https://github.com/Pylons/colander) from Pylons
- [schematics](http://schematics.readthedocs.io/)

For easier cases you can also use something from standard library like

- [named tuples](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.NamedTuple) and one from [collections](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) which is available also in py2
- [SimpleNamespace](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html?highlight=simplenamespace#types.SimpleNamespace)

Comment: of course you will first need to [parse json](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html)

Comment: thanks @code22  can you give me some libs support 3.6?

Answer (score 1):

In order to do that you should provide your custom callback as an `object_hook` argument to the `json.loads` function.

> `object_hook` is an optional function that will be called with the
>   result of any object literal decode (a `dict`). The return value of
>   `object_hook` will be used instead of the `dict`. This feature
>   can be used to implement custom decoders (e.g. JSON-RPC class hinting).

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [***collections.namestuple***](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) subclasses:

```
json_str = '''
{
   "id":"123",
   "name":"name",
   "key":{
      "id":"345",
      "des":"des"
    }
}'''

B = collections.namedtuple('B', 'id des')
A = collections.namedtuple('A', 'id name key')

def make_models(o):
    if 'key' in o:
        return A(o['id'], o['name'], B(id=o['key']['id'], des=o['key']['des']))
    else:
        return o

result = json.loads(json_str, object_hook=make_models)

print(type(result))    # outputs: <class '__main__.A'>
print(result.id)       # outputs: 123
print(result.key.id)   # outputs: 345
```

Comment: how if i got heaps of properties, i am new to python, and on python 3.6 , thanks

Comment: as you saw `collections.namedtuple('B', 'id des')` : `id` and `des` are properties. Add new properties in same way

Comment: yes, i got what you mean, but some times the key from json is a keyword, like `class` or `str`, and how about i got 100 properties.