# Why won't a simple dictionary populate obj properly for form = myForm(obj=dict)?

Tags: wtforms

I'm having trouble populating a form using a dictionary:

```
        row = {'firstname':'Bob', 'lastname': "Smith",
               'email': 'bob@bubba.com', 'phone': '512.999.1212'}
        form = RolodexEntry(obj=row)
```

doesn't put any data into form (i.e. form.firstname.data = None after the preceding).

The top of the form definition is shown below.   I'm at a loss for what to try next.  The form documentation just says:

> obj – If formdata is empty or not provided, this object is checked for attributes matching form field names, which will be used for field values.

```
class RolodexEntry(Form):
    firstname  = TextField('First Name',[validators.length(max=40)],
                           filters=[strip_filter])
    lastname   = TextField('Last Name', [validators.length(max=40)],
                           filters=[strip_filter])
    email      = TextField('Email',     [validators.Optional(),
                                         validators.length(max=25),
                                         validators.Email()],
                           filters=[strip_filter])
    ...
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The issue is the WTForms [only use `getattr` to check if the field name exists in `obj`](https://bitbucket.org/simplecodes/wtforms/src/198dc0f42c7e/wtforms/form.py?at=default#cl-104) (it doesn't try to invoke `__getitem__`).  You can use a [`namedtuple`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) instead of a dictionary or you can pass in your data as keyword arguments (`form = RolodexEntry(**row)`).

Comment: Overriding `process` is a bad idea. One can simply pass the dictionary as `**row` to the Form constructor if a dict is required.

Answer (score 10):

This answer included for completeness.  As pointed out by Sean Vieira, WTForms is using `getattr` to get attribute names, which doesn't work with dictionaries.  Using the accepted answer from

[Convert Python dict to object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1305532/convert-python-dict-to-object)

This also works:

```
class Struct:
    def __init__(self, **entries):
        self.__dict__.update(entries)

row = {'firstname':'Bob', 'lastname': "Smith",
       'email': 'bob@bubba.com', 'phone': '512.999.1212'}
rowobj = Struct(**row)
form = RolodexEntry(obj=rowobj)
```

Comment: This worked for me over the accepted answer. Also in my case I had to add `RolodexEntry(formdata=None, obj=rowobj)`.

Answer (score 1):

Albeit this question was asked a while ago, I suggest to see [Sean Vieira's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32063210/4442749) to a duplicate of this question. As explained in his answer, any class with an interface including `getlist` will be accepted by the `wtforms.Form` constructor.

Answer (score 1):

according to Sean Vieira 's answer and in my flask app, I write my code like this:

```
from collections import namedtuple
UpdateSchema= namedtuple('UpdateSchema', ['name', 'real_name', 'email', 'phone'])
update_schema = UpdateSchema(
    name= current_user.name,
    real_name=current_user.job_hunter.real_name,
    email=current_user.email,
    phone=current_user.job_hunter.phone
)
form = UpdateJobHunterForm(obj=update_schema)
```

my app is a job find website, and I suggest you do not write like :

```
update_schema = dict(
    'name': current_user.name,
    'real_name':current_user.job_hunter.real_name,
    'email':current_user.email,
    'phone':current_user.job_hunter.phone
)
form = UpdateJobHunterForm(**update_schema)
```

In this way, if I want to upload a file, the request wont get the file filed data, so do not write in the second way!!

Answer (score 0):

When I was using flask_wtf, I found Flask's form class was messing me up. I think this was the same issue from @wgwz's comment to @pgoetz's answer. The Flask form automatically populated formdata with data from the request. Since my "RolodexEntry" was a FormField embedded in a larger Form, the automatically-populated formdata was invalid. To try to fix this, instead of subclassing Flask's Form, I subclassed wtforms' Form.