# tab complete dictionary keys in ipython

Tags: python, dictionary, ipython, tab-completion

I was wondering if anybody knows how to enable or implement tab completion for dictionary keys in IPython?  It seems like it wouldn't be very different from functionality that already exists, like tab completion of object attributes.  If I'm wrong, then I'd like to understand why

Comment: Just to clarify: you mean that if `d = {"apple": 1, "banana":2}`, then if you type `d["a"]` and put the cursor after `a`, you'd want `apple` to be filled in?

Comment: @DavidRobinson I imagine I would tye `d["a` and hit tab and it would complete to `d["apple"]`

Comment: Thanks pointing at the matter. Made a report from this at https://bugs.launchpad.net/python-mode/+bug/1251690

Answer (score 9, accepted):

IPython supports dict key completion for string keys since version 3.0.0 (despite not appearing in release notes), thanks to [this patch](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/pull/5304). It also supports column name completion for numpy struct arrays and pandas `DataFrame` columns, and for other types that redefine `__getitem__` through defining [`_ipython_key_completions_`](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/integrating.html).

Comment: Great, this is a nice way of implementing completion for your own `subscriptable` classes.

Answer (score 2):

It's not built into IPython 2.x. If you want to add it, have a look at this, where someone hacked a solution:

https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/1533

Also, there are many short and easy ways to create objects from dictionaries, to gain the usual tab completion. If that would help you, use one of the ways described in this question:

[Convert Python dict to object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1305532/convert-python-dict-to-object)

Comment: No longer true, see my answer.