# tab complete key for __getitem__ in Python class

Tags: python, readline, prompt-toolkit

I'm implementing a python class that contains a 2d numpy array (`self.data`) that I have set up for column access with a string key. 
The keys are contained in a dict that maps names to column indices (e.g., `self.coldict={'col0':0,...,'colN':N}`), and I've defined

```
def __getitem__(self,key):
   if isinstance(key,str):
       return self.data[:,self.coldict[key]]
   elif isinstance(key,int):
       return self.data[:,key]
```

This works as intended for column retrieval.

I'd like to be able to use tab complete for the key so that I can type 
`myObject['c+TAB` during an iPython session to get completion options.

I think a solution should rely on readline or prompt_toolkit, but it's not clear to me how to implement a completer function without overriding the already-active functionality in iPython.

Any help is much appreciated. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you can tab complete a string for `__getitem__`. Tab completion is usually for object attribtues. Tab completion uses the items defined in the `__dict__` instance dictionary and the `__dir__(self)` method.

If you want tab completion for the accessing an attribute you can.

```
class MyArray:
    ...
    def __dir__(self):
        return super().__dir__() + list(self.coldict.keys())

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        if name in self.coldict:
            return self.data[:,self.coldict[name]]
        return super().__getattr__(name)
```

You would then access your column with

```
arr = MyArray() # My numpy array
print(arr.col0) # col0 should allow for tab complete.
```

Comment: Thanks! That's an excellent workaround.  Pandas has the behavior I'm looking for implemented for dataframes, but I haven't managed to find that code in the source yet. That does indicate that it is possible (though it doesn't mean it's easy!).

Answer (score 1):

It was hard to track down, but this is how it's done (reference [1](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/integrating.html#tab-completion) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17974777/tab-complete-dictionary-keys-in-ipython)):

> You can also customize key completions for your objects, e.g. pressing tab after `obj["a`. To do so, define a method `_ipython_key_completions_()`, which returns a list of objects which are possible keys in a subscript expression `obj[key]`.

I got this working by simply adding a method called `_ipython_key_completions_` to a custom class that returns all the possible string keys that can be used when calling `__getitem__`. What I didn't realize is that Python `dict`s already do this as well as Pandas DataFrames.

Comment: Note that if you also define `__getattr__()` of the class, then the `_ipython_key_completions_` somehow won't work.