# Authenticating a non-ORM User Resource via TastyPie

Tags: python, django, authentication, tastypie

I am trying to use Django with a non-ORM data source, and while accessing other resources through my custom backend without any authentication is successful, now I need to introduce user authentication. There is no local database. When I receive a request (e.g., a cURL command made with username and password), I need to perform HTTP Basic Authentication against a remote URL and upon success, I should return a locally created user object, which only has a username, nothing fancy. So in my Tastypie resource, I wrote something like this:

```
class dict2obj(object):
    """
    Convert dictionary to object
    @source http://stackoverflow.com/a/1305561/383912
    """
    def __init__(self, d):
        self.__dict__['d'] = d

    def __getattr__(self, key):
        value = self.__dict__['d'][key]
        if type(value) == type({}):
            return dict2obj(value)
        return value


class RemoteAuth(Authentication):
    def is_authenticated(self, request, **kwargs):
        username = request.user.username
        password = request.user.password
        r = requests.get(AUTHENTICATION_URL, auth=(username, password))
        if r.status_code == 200:
          return True
        return False



class UserResource(Resource):             
    username = fields.CharField(attribute='username')

    class Meta:
        resource_name = 'user'
        authentication = RemoteAuth()
        authorization = Authorization()

        def obj_get_list(self, request=None, **kwargs):

            result = []

            posts.append(dict2obj(
            {
            'username': request.POST.get('username'),
            }
            ))

            return result
```

But of course this does not work, because the authentication object cannot obtain password like that. Please suggest a good way of handling remove user authentication without involving any local database.

Comment: Have you tried storing the `username` and `password` in `session` after successful request to your login endpoint? You could serve the login API via SSL to make it a little more secure.

Comment: I am not sure how that is to be done. Could you point me to some sample code? I was under the impression that a Tastypie resource is an endpoint. I am trying to access `http://localost:8000/api/v1/user/?format=json`

Comment: I will submit it as a separate answer, as it is difficult to include inline code in comments

Comment: Looking forward to it :)

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to have user authentication without storing any actual data on your side, then you could use `session` or, as last resort, `cookies`. The session data could be encrypted and stored inside the session cookie itself, or a side cookie.

**How that would work?**

You could create an endpoint, say `api/v1/user/login`, as the `UserResource` method to handle user authentication/login. You can do so like this:

```
def override_urls(self):
    return [
        url(r"^(?P<resource_name>%s)/login%s$" % (self._meta.resource_name, trailing_slash()), self.wrap_view('user_login'), name="api_user_login"),
    ]

def user_login(self, request, **kwargs):
    # Authentication process happens here.
    return self.create_response(request, {})
```

For the above to work, you have to import `tastypie.utils.trailing_slash` and `django.conf.urls.url`. Unfortunately, tastypie doesn't support any helper method to creating urls less painfully.

In the `user_login` method, you would then authenticate credentials passed via `POST` against the remote endpoint and store the username and password in the `request.session` along with any remote-authentication-endpoint-specific data. In the `RemoteAuthentication` you could then check for the session keys existence.

If the session is data in your local filesystem, then the data inside can be considered a little more secure. If you decide to store the session data in an encrypted cookie, you would have to store a value and a checksum for each session key, possibly in a single cookie entry, or seperate ones.

Since the users would be passing their credentials in plain text to login, you could consider serving the `user_login` view via SSL (make sure the cookie is not `secure_only` then).

Comment: But the reason I want BasicAuthentication on the whole resource is that I do not want to stay logged in. Random requests will be made using cURL or Jquery/Ajax on methods of a resource. Every request will be made with username and password, not necessarily the same one every time.

Comment: Then you can pass username and password in custom headers, i.e. `X-MYAPP-ID` and `X-MYAPP-PASSWORD` and get those values from `request.META` in your `RemoteAuthentication` and authenticate the user against the remote service