# Problems when converting a dictionary to object

Tags: python, class, dictionary

I am using a technique discussed here before, to turn a dictionary into an object, so that I can access the elements of the dictionary with the dot (.) notion, as instance variables.

This is what I am doing:

```
# Initial dictionary
myData = {'apple':'1', 'banana':'2', 'house':'3', 'car':'4', 'hippopotamus':'5'}

# Create the container class
class Struct:
    def __init__(self, **entries):
        self.__dict__.update(entries)

# Finally create the instance and bind the dictionary to it
k = Struct(**myData)
```

So now, I can do:

```
print k.apple
```

and the result is:

```
1
```

This works, however the issues start if I try to add some other methods to the "Struct" class. For example lets say that I am adding a simple method that just creates an variable:

```
class Struct:
    def __init__(self, **entries):
        self.__dict__.update(entries)

    def testMe(self):
        self.myVariable = 67
```

If I do:

```
k.testMe()
```

My dictionary object is broken, "myVariable" is inserted as a key with the value "67". So If I do:

```
print k.__dict__
```

I am getting:

```
{'apple': '1', 'house': '3', 'myVariable': 67, 'car': '4', 'banana': '2', 'hippopotamus': '5'}
```

Is there a way to fix this? I kind of understand what is happening, but not sure If I need to entirely change my approach and build a class with internal methods to handle the dictionary object or is there a simpler way to fix this problem?

Here is the original link:
[Convert Python dict to object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1305532/convert-python-dict-to-object)

Thanks.

Comment: Attributes of object instances are stored in the so called *instance dict* that can be accessed through `obj.__dict__` - did you intentionally choose that name for your dict because you want it to "look like a real object", or was that accidental? Because if not, you should just use something like `self._dict` (initialize it first) and you'll be good.

Comment: Or to phrase it differently: Yes, of course `myVariable` is inserted as a key to your object's `__dict__` - that's how it's supposed to work. Isn't that what you want? I don't see how this "breaks" your dict.

Comment: @LukasGraf Hi, thanks for the prompt reply. I have just followed the instructions in that link. Let me try, but I suspect that, If I do not use `__dict__` I am not going to get the `.item` access. I will try it now.

Comment: No, you won't get dotted attribute access if you don't use `obj.__dict__`. You could however use a `namedtuple` (IIRC there's also an example for that in the other answer).

Comment: Well, I do not want every variable that I create in my class, to be inserted in the dictionary, I would like to be able to have some more internal functionality without contaminating my dictionary. If possible of course?

Comment: so you want *two kinds* of attribute, which are the same for the purposes of `getattr()` but different in-re to `setattr()`?  what's the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: I am tying to create a dynamic object, that stores the dictionary keys and items, and gives access to them through the usual `obj.key = value` so that when I do: `s = Struct(**myDictionary)` then I can do `s.apple` and get the `value`. But also have additional methods inside that class that I can use for other things, for example: `s.formattedDump()` to print the dictionary in a formatted way etc. The problem with the current state is that I cannot really add any other method to that class, any methods I build will have internal variables, any attempt contaminates my dictionary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For your needs, don't store you variables in `__dict__`. Use your own dictionary instead, and override `.__getattr__` (for `print k.apple`) and `__setattr__` (for `k.apple=2`):

```
# Initial dictionary
myData = {'apple':'1', 'banana':'2', 'house':'3', 'car':'4', 'hippopotamus':'5'}

# Create the container class
class Struct:
    _dict = {}
    def __init__(self, **entries):
        self._dict = entries

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        try:
            return self._dict[name]
        except KeyError:
            raise AttributeError(
                "'{}' object has no attribute or key '{}'".format(
                    self.__class__.__name__, name))


    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        if name in self._dict:
            self._dict[name] = value
        else:
            self.__dict__[name] = value

    def testMe(self):
        self.myVariable = 67

    def FormattedDump(self):
        return str(self._dict)

# Finally create the instance and bind the dictionary to it
k = Struct(**myData)

print k.apple
print k.FormattedDump()
k.testMe()
k.apple = '2'
print k.FormattedDump()
```

---

In the alternative, if your `FormattedDump()` routine is bothering you, you could just fix *it*:

```
# Initial dictionary
myData = {'apple':'1', 'banana':'2', 'house':'3', 'car':'4', 'hippopotamus':'5'}

# Create the container class
class Struct:
    def __init__(self, **entries):
        self.__dict__.update(entries)
        self.public_names = entries.keys()

    def testMe(self):
        self.myVariable = 67

    def GetPublicDict(self):
        return {key:getattr(self, key) for key in self.public_names}
    def FormattedDump(self):
        return str(self.GetPublicDict())

# Finally create the instance and bind the dictionary to it
k = Struct(**myData)

print k.apple
print k.FormattedDump()
k.testMe()
k.apple = '2'
print k.FormattedDump()
```

Comment: Removed my answer in favor of yours since you're gonna expand on `__setattr__`.

Comment: You should however raise `AttributeError` in `__getattr__`, a missing key in `self._dict` would otherwise raise a `KeyError` instead, which would be rather unexpected for dotted attribute access.

Comment: Hi! Thank you very much for the help! I will try it immediately. This already looks pretty cool, thanks for all the help and the advice.

Comment: @symbolix - You are welcome. But do consider my 2nd alternative. If seems much more elegant to me.

Comment: Sure. This looks like a valuable way to learn more about classes etc. I got really confused in my initial code, when any variable I was trying to utilise in order to perform an operation was being added to my dictionary. So the solution that was my starting point was actually wrong?!

Comment: @symbolix the issue was that `__dict__` has a very special meaning in Python (like all `__magic__` names), and is used by Python itself. See [`obj.__dict__`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#object.__dict__) and [The Standard Type Hierarchy, Section *Class Instances*](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#the-standard-type-hierarchy)

Comment: Works great! Thanks for the solution. Using the second, elegant approach :)