# How to extract string values into object fields

Tags: python

I have this dictionary:

```
{"id":3,"name":"MySQL","description":"MySQL Database Server - Fedora 21 - medium","image":"","flavor":""}
```

And I have this object:

```
class Record():
    id = None
    name = None
    description = None
    image = None
    flavor = None
```

How can I assign values from the dictionary to their corresponding class fields?

Comment: Are those variables supposed to be class variables or instance variables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a dict object as the parameter of **init** function:

```
class Record(object):
  def __init__(self,record_dict):
    try:
      self.id = record_dict['id']
      self.name = record_dict['name']
      self.description = record_dict['description']
      self.image = record_dict['image']
      self.flavor = record_dict['flavor']
    except KeyError:
      print 'KeyError'

  def get_name(self):
    return self.name

adict = {"id":3,"name":"MySQL","description":"MySQL Database Server - Fedora 21 - medium","image":"","flavor":""}

one_obj = Record(adict)

print one_obj
print one_obj.get_name()
```

output:

```
<__main__.Record object at 0x022E4C90>
MySQL
```

works for me...

Comment: I did as abovem but getting:  record = Record()
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)

Comment: Of course, you forgot to pass the dict as  parameter.

Comment: I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Here is exactly how I call it:  one_obj = Record(adict)  , and I still get TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)

Comment: What's your Python version?

Comment: I have to use 2.7.6 - as I'm extending OpenStack Horizon, and that is what they use

Comment: My version is 2.7.8, I don't know why, too.Sorry about that.

Comment: Sorry - I was using the original Record() in one other place, and that is what's giving me issue!

Comment: You are right - in a separate environment this works just fine. I've got to figure out why it fails in my Horizon environment

Comment: As it turns out, I was dealing with string, not a dict. Once I fixed that, your method worked perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You probably want something like this:

```
class Record:
def __init__(self, myDict):
    self.id = myDict[“id”]
    self.name = myDict[“name”]
    self.description = myDict[“description”]
    self.image = myDict[“image”]
    self.flavor = myDict[“flavor”]
```

And call it:

```
rec = Record(myDict)
```

See [here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#class-and-instance-variables) to understand the difference between class and instance variables.

Long story short, class variables have a single value for every instance of the class while instance variables values are unique to each instance.

A class variable is defined like this:

```
class myClass:
    Classvar =  ‘something’
```

An instance variable is defined like this:

```
class myClass:
    def __init__():
        Self.instanceVar = ‘something else’
```

Comment: I suppose - instance variables

Answer (score 2):

This has already been answered here:
[Convert Python dict to object?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1305532/584846)

My favorite method is this one: [`x.__dict__.update(d)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1305548/584846)

Answer (score 1):

You can assign them as follows, assuming your dictionary name is `input`

```
id = input['id']
name = input['name']
description = input['description']
image = input['image']
flavor = input['flavor']
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this method in which you grab the attributes of the object:

```
r = Record()
attributes = [i for i in dir(r) if not i.startswith('_')]
```

Basically, there are a bunch of background attributes that contain a bunch of underscores. The `dir` method gets all the attributes and we create a list of the ones that we want. At this point:

```
# attributes = ['count', 'description', 'flavor', 'id', 'image', 'index', 'name']
```

So now we use `__setattr__` to set the attributes we just grabbed according to the `my_dict`

```
for i in attributes:
    r.__setattr__(i, my_dict[i])
```

See the code run online [here](http://repl.it/8kM/2).

Comment: `Record` must explicitly inherit from the `object` class.

Answer (score 0):

When you create the Record, pass in the dictionary. Then map the key to the value.

Answer (score 0):

Another simple method, see the code [here](http://repl.it/8kS)

```
r = Record()

for k, v in my_dict.items():
    exec('r.' + k + '="' + str(v) + '"')
```

Comment: What do you guys think? Just a simple `exec` to set the attributes.