# Lua-like dict in Python

Tags: python, dictionary

In Lua you can address keys of the dictionary like attributes:

```
d = {a = 1, b = 1}
d['a'] == d.a -- this returns true
```

Is there something like that in Python? I've noticed that sklearn bunch objects have similar properties.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert Python dict to object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1305532/convert-python-dict-to-object)

Comment: I guess, one of the reasons that Lua uses `d.a` a syntax sugar of `d['a']` is that Lua uses `t:func()` in its own unique OOP style. That's not the case for Python.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the only valid ways to access a `dict` using a key are `d['a']` or `d.get('a')`

The former may raise a `KeyError` if that key is not in the `dict`, and the latter takes a second optional argument that it will return if the key is not found.

Answer (score 2):

You can make a class and use setattr to access attributes that way, though it seems kinda excessive just for convenience. You could do it with any old object too, but I wouldn't recommend it.