# Converting a nested dict to Python object

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have this nested dictionary that I get from an API.

```
response_body = \
{  
    u'access_token':u'SIF_HMACSHA256lxWT0K',
    u'expires_in':86000,
    u'name':u'Gandalf Grey',
    u'preferred_username':u'gandalf',
    u'ref_id':u'ab1d4237-edd7-4edd-934f-3486eac5c262',
    u'refresh_token':u'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1N',
    u'roles':u'Instructor',
    u'sub':{  
        u'cn':u'Gandalf Grey',
        u'dc':u'7477',
        u'uid':u'gandalf',
        u'uniqueIdentifier':u'ab1d4237-edd7-4edd-934f-3486eac5c262'
    }
}
```

I used the following to convert it into a Python object:

```
class sample_token:
    def __init__(self, **response):
        self.__dict__.update(response)
```

and used it like this:

```
s = sample_token(**response_body)
```

After this, I can access the values using `s.access_token`, `s.name` etc. But the value of `c.sub` is also a dictionary. How can I get the values of the nested dictionary using this technique? i.e. `s.sub.cn` returns `Gandalf Grey`.

Comment: What's the reason you want to do that? Why not just `response_body['sub']['cn']` ?

Comment: @MattDMo The data is already in python dict. This question doesn't have much to do with json itself really, just nested dictionaries.

Comment: @viraptor Well, I was trying out some alternatives.

Comment: @viraptor you're right, I was taking the OP at his word. It's late...

Comment: @MattDMo I have changed that as well. I hope its good now.

Comment: @Animesh missed the title, but I got it. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe a recursive method like this -

```
>>> class sample_token:
...     def __init__(self, **response):
...         for k,v in response.items():
...             if isinstance(v,dict):
...                 self.__dict__[k] = sample_token(**v)
...             else:
...                 self.__dict__[k] = v
...
>>> s = sample_token(**response_body)
>>> s.sub
<__main__.sample_token object at 0x02CEA530>
>>> s.sub.cn
'Gandalf Grey'
```

We go over each `key:value` pair in the response, and if value is a dictionary we create a sample_token object for that and put that new object in the `__dict__()` .

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over all key/value pairs with `response.items()` and for each value which `isinstance(value, dict)`, replace it with `sample_token(**value)`.

Nothing will do the recursion automagically for you.

Answer (score 0):

Once you've evaluated the expression in Python, it's not a JSON object anymore; it's a Python `dict`; the usual way to access entries is with the `[]` indexer notation, e.g.:

```
response_body['sub']['uid']
'gandalf'
```

If you **must** access it as an object rather than a dict, check out the answers in the question [Convert Python dict to object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1305532/convert-python-dict-to-object); the case of nested dicsts is covered in one  of the later answers.