# Query in namedtuple, attribute error

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pyramid

Working with `namedtuple` and I'm trying to put a query into it.

```
build = namedtuple('build', 'x y z')
build(x=DB.query(x).filter(x.id == 'query').first(),
      y=DB.query(y).filter(y.id == 'query').first(),
      z=DB.query(z).filter(z.id == 'query').first())
```

When I actually try to access `x` with `print build.x.id` I get:

```
AttributeError: 'property' object has no attribute 'id'
```

I think this has to do with having a query within the namedtuple, and I'm just doing it wrong or it isn't designed to do this. I've googled around and I don't see much on this.

Comment: Try: `print build.x['id']`

Comment: Tried that too. get this error: `TypeError: 'property' object has no attribute '__getitem__'`

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with `namedtuple` (but it might); can you give us some context on what exactly `DB` is? It just seems like whatever you're putting into `build` isn't actually what you think it is.

Comment: Probably should've noted but thought it was assumed since I put `pyramid` as a tag. I'm using `sqlalchemy`, so the resulting query of `x` would normally be something like `<DB.models.x object at 0x105f70290>` in which I could then go, `print x.id` and I would get say, an integer.

Comment: Is you sample code exactly what you use in your real program? Asking because I can run your code without any problems.

Comment: It's close enough. Try connecting it up to a real database, replace `x` with an actual table. I couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a workaround that doesn't used `namedtuple`, as I don't think that's appropriate for my usecase (ie, I don't think it supports nested dicts/objects without finangling)

Found this question, [Convert Python dict to object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1305532/convert-python-dict-to-object) and decided to adjust my code to use that instead.

```
build = {'x': DB.query(x).filter(x.id == 'query').first()}
build = bunchify(build)
```

Which now allows me to do

```
>>> print build.x.id
27
```

seamlessly.

*Simple is better than complex.*