# Split the title part of the URL into a separate column - Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, urlparse

Suppose I have a URL as follows:

```
http://sitename.com/pathname?title=moviename&url=VIDEO_URL
```

I want to parse this URL to get the title part and url part alone separately.

I tried the following,

```
from urlparse import urlparse
q = urlparse('http://sitename.com/pathname?title=moviename&url=VIDEO_URL')
```

After I do this, I get the following result,

```
q
ParseResult(scheme='http', netloc='sitename.com', path='/pathname', params='', query='title=moviename&url=VIDEO_URL', fragment='')
```

and `q.query` has,

```
'title=moviename&url=VIDEO_URL'
```

I am not able to use q.query.title or q.query.url here. Is there a way I can access this? I would like to split the url and title part separately into separate columns. Can we do it this way or can we write a substring method which would check for starting with "title" and ending with "&" and split it?

Thanks

Comment: Try: q.query.split('&')

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `urlparse.parse_qs` here to make a dictionary of parameters.

```
from urlparse import urlparse, parse_qs
q = urlparse('http://sitename.com/pathname?title=moviename&url=VIDEO_URL')
qs = parse_qs(q.query)
print qs["title"] # moviename
print qs["url"] # VIDEO_URL
```

This is the most reliable way to parse a URL's parameters: much better than `split`.

Answer (score 1):

`urlparse` can parse the url, from there get `query` and parse that:

```
>>> import urlparse
>>> url = 'http://sitename.com/pathname?title=moviename&url=VIDEO_URL'
>>> urlparse.parse_qs(urlparse.urlparse(url).query)
{'title': ['moviename'], 'url': ['VIDEO_URL']}
```

As the query string parameter can appear multiple times, the dictionary provides list of found values (even when there is only one value found.)

Answer (score 0):

You're doing it right, it's just that a standard URL is made of:

```
<SCHEME>://<NETLOC>/<PATH>?<QUERY>
```

so what you want to extract the details from the query is to split the string, like that, if you like *the dirty way*:

```
>>> data = dict(item.split('=') for item in q.query.split('&'))
>>> data
{'url': 'VIDEO_URL', 'title': 'moviename'}
>>> print(data['url'])
```

and there you have your URL! This a a very basic and canonical version of what the `urlparse` library offers through the [`parse_qsl()` method](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/urlparse.py#l390). That method also converts `+` into spaces, handles ';' as well as `&` and unquotes the URL.

So to use urlparse's `parse_qsl` function, all you have to do is:

```
>> data =urlparse.parse_qsl(q.query)
{'url': 'VIDEO_URL', 'title': 'moviename'}
>>> print(data['url'])
```

N.B.: it's **NOT safer** to use `parse_qsl` than the `split()` method, but **more RELIABLE**. The main difference is that `parse_qsl` will work with all possible use cases of queries as defined by the RFC, whereas the `split()` method works with a single case.

Answer (score 0):

These answers are spot on for parsing the query string. To go a step further and also use dot notation, also see [Convert Python dict to object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1305532/convert-python-dict-to-object)

```
from collections import namedtuple
QS = namedtuple('QS', qs.keys())
dotted_qs = QS(**qs)
dotted_qs.url #['moviename']
```

Note that the `dict` that comes back from `parse_qs` can be multi-valued, hence the list return type of `dotted.url`. You can collapse it to single value with a dict comprehension or `parse_qsl`:

```
qs = {k: v[0] for k, v in q.query.items()}
```

Or...

```
qs = dict(urlparse.parse_qsl(q.query.items()))
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score -1):

To get just the query parameters split by the '&' you can use:

`q.query.split('&')`

Or to get pairs of parameter/value you can use:

`args = [tuple(arg.split('=')) for arg in q.query.split('&')]`