# Python convert json to python object and visit attribute using comma

Tags: python

As title, A json object or convert to a python object like:

```
u = {
    "name": "john",
    "coat": {
        "color": "red",
        "sex": "man",
    },
    "groups": [
        {"name": "git"},
        {"name": "flask"}
    ]
}
```

I want visit as:

```
u.name
```

It's easy to do with inherit from dict, but

```
u.groups.0.name
```

We also set it as

```
u.name = "flask"
u.groups.0.name = "svn"
```

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert Python dict to object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1305532/convert-python-dict-to-object)

Comment: `u.groups.0.name` is not going to be possible, since it's not valid python syntax

Comment: @FranciscoCouzo, second that, to be more specific - valid Python ID cannot start with number.

Answer (score 1):

Python is not JavaScript. You need to refer to `u["groups"][0]["name"]`.

Answer (score 0):

May be it's difficult, because integer as key is invalid.

I do like this

```html
class Dict(dict):
    def __init__(self, value):
        if isinstance(value, (list, tuple)):
            value = dict(zip(['_%s' % i for i in range(len(value))], value))
            super(Dict, self).__init__(value)

    def __getattr__(self, key):
        try:
            if type(self.__getitem__(key)) in (dict, OrderedDict, tuple, list):
                return Dict(self.__getitem__(key))
            return self.__getitem__(key)
        except KeyError:
            raise AttributeError(key)

    def __setattr__(self, key, value):
        try:
            return self.__setitem__(key, value)
        except KeyError:
            raise AttributeError(key)
```

```
u = {
    "name": "john",
    "coat": {
        "color": "red",
        "sex": "man",
    },
    "groups": [
        {"name": "git"},
        {"name": "flask"}
    ]
}

>>> u = Dict(u)
>>> u.name 
output: john
>>> u.groups._0 
output: {"name": "git"}
```