# How to pass a Hydra config via command line

Tags: python-3.x, fb-hydra

There's already a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60674012/how-to-get-a-hydra-config-without-using-hydra-main), however the proposed [Compose API](https://hydra.cc/docs/advanced/compose_api/) no longer supports passing a config as an argument by Hydra 0.11.3.

I'm wondering if there is a way to pass the config via command line or whether this functionality is disabled in the latest version ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The compose API does support passing the config as an argument

In Hydra 1.0.0rc1, there is a new command line flag `--config-name`.

- [Release notes](https://github.com/facebookresearch/hydra/releases/tag/hydra-1.0.0rc1)
- [Related issue](https://github.com/facebookresearch/hydra/issues/386) (See last comment for description of what is supported).

Comment: Probably obvious to everyone but me, but e.g. if you want to run `myapp.py` and the relative path to the config file that you want to use is `path/to/config/my-config.yaml`, youl should do: `python myapp.py -cd path/to/config --config-name=my-config`.