# Returning the config from the function decorated with hydra.main()

Tags: python, fb-hydra

Is there an option to get from the function under *@hydra.main* decorator the configuration object as a dictionary?

I tried something like this, but it returns *None*

```
@hydra.main(config_path="conf", config_name="config")
def my_app(cfg) -> dict:
    print(cfg) # --> work, the cfg object exists inside the function scope
    return cfg
a = my_app()
print(a)
```

I know I can use the [compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60674012/how-to-get-a-hydra-config-without-using-hydra-main) API, but I prefer not to use it due to its limited functionality (Tab completion, Multirun etc.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.
`@hydra.main()` does not return a value intentionally. (What would you expect the return value to be if you use `--multirun` and your function returns multiple times?)

Call your logic from within your `@hydra.main` function and pass the cfg object to it.