# Using hydra.main on main method

Tags: python-3.x, fb-hydra

Summary of the problem:

1. I'm running a requests call on an API endpoint, whose request params are hidden in a config file and I decided to try out hydra to retrieve those params [Reason being the request params do change as I'm working on collecting custom dataset using RapidAPI]
2. I have created a class called QueryParamsLocations which implements the getter methods to fetch the parameters to be later used by run_query method.

```
class QueryParamsLocations(QueryParams):
    
    @hydra.main(config_path='configs', config_name='location_query')
    def get_params_query_string(self, cfg: DictConfig) -> dict():
        return {
            'query': cfg.location_params.query,
            'locale': cfg.location_params.locale,
            'currency': cfg.location_params.currency
        }
    
    @hydra.main(config_path='configs', config_name='location_query')
    def get_url(self, cfg: DictConfig) -> str():
        return cfg.urls.location_url

    @hydra.main(config_path='configs', config_name='location_query')
    def get_headers(self, cfg: DictConfig) -> dict():
        return {
            'X-RapidAPI-Host': cfg.headers.x_rapidapi_host, 
            'X-RapidAPI-Key': cfg.headers.x_rapidapi_key
        }
```

3. class QueryParams is an abstract class which has these 3 getter templates. run_query method is an external call to run the request.

```
@hydra.main(config_path='configs', config_name='location_query')
def run_query(cfg: DictConfig) -> None:
    try:
        LoggerFactory.get_logger('logs/logger.log', 'INFO').info('Running query for location')
        qpl = QueryParamsLocations()    
        response = requests.request("GET", qpl.get_url(cfg), headers=qpl.get_headers(cfg), params=qpl.get_params_query_string(cfg))
        print(response.json())
    except Exception as e:
        LoggerFactory.get_logger('logs/logger.log',
                                 'ERROR').error(f'Error in running query: {e}')


run_query()
```

4. While running run_query without if **name** == '**main**': and with it as well , the following error is encountered :

```
[2022-05-16 13:43:32,614][logs/logger.log][ERROR] - Error in running query: **decorated_main()** takes from 0 to 1 positional arguments but 2 were given
```

Although newer version of hydra (I'm using `hydra-core==1.1.2`) uses two arguments while creating cfg object however , I'm not sure as to whether there's other way of handling this as such.

Also, by searching through other threads, following was also tried - [Compose API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60674012/how-to-get-a-hydra-config-without-using-hydra-main)

however, from the docs, it requires an override parameter , which is not needed atm.

Would like to know if any other approach can be tried out. Happy to provide more details if needed.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely use the Compose API and not `hydra.main()` for this use case.
You can just pass an empty array for your override list if you have nothing to override.

Comment: Many thanks , trying this out and updating.

Comment: Used the Compose API , by replacing the hydra.main decorator in the above snippet , still getting the same error @OmryYadan

Comment: You are not getting an error about decorated_main while using the compose API. As far as I remember it's only called from hydra.main().

Comment: True that , I digged a bit deeper on this and it seems to be the one from the methods under the QueryParamsLocations class , as I changed the config implementation of run_query from hydra.main to Compose.

Comment: Please accept if this solved your problem.