# Pythonic way to read JSON list into python class

Tags: python

Consider the following code

```py
import json


class Address(object):
    def __init__(self, street, number):
        self.street = street
        self.number = number

    def __str__(self):
        return "{0} {1}".format(self.street, self.number)


class User(object):
    address: List[Address] = []

    def __init__(self, name, address: List):
        self.name = name
        for adr in address:
            self.address.append(Address(*adr)) # is this needed?

    def __str__(self):
        return "{0} ,{1}".format(self.name, self.address)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    js = '''{
    "name": "Cristian",
    "address": [{
            "street": "Sesame",
            "number": 122
        },
        {
            "street": "Sesame",
            "number": 122
        }
    ]
}'''
    j = json.loads(js)
    print(j)
    u = User(**j)
    print(u.name)
    print(u.address[0].number)
```

my question is, for this type of JSON where we have a list of values. Do we need to loop through the list? Or is there a more pythonic way to simply fill this object

```py
address: List[Address] = []
```

from the loaded json?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1305532/convert-nested-python-dict-to-object

Comment: Do you really need the class `Address`? By the way it should be `Address(**adr))` since you are unpacking a dictionary

Comment: @cards no adr is a list not a dict the first json called j in the code is a dict.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prefer [dataclasses](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/dataclasses.html), [json dataclasses](https://github.com/lidatong/dataclasses-json) in python

```
from typing import List
import json

from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from dataclasses_json import dataclass_json


class Address(object):
    def __init__(self, street, number):
        self.street = street
        self.number = number

    def __str__(self):
        return "{0} {1}".format(self.street, self.number)


@dataclass_json
@dataclass
class User(object):
    address: List[Address] = field(default_factory=lambda: [])
    name: str = None

    def __str__(self):
        return "{0} ,{1}".format(self.name, self.address)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    js = '''{
    "name": "Cristian",
    "address": [{
            "street": "Sesame",
            "number": 122
        },
        {
            "street": "Sesame",
            "number": 122
        }
    ]
    }'''

    data = User.from_dict(json.loads(js))
    print(data)
```

If you use `__str__` in `User` it will print

```
Cristian ,[{'street': 'Sesame', 'number': 122}, {'street': 'Sesame', 'number': 122}]
```

else if you omit `__str__` in `User` it will print

```
User(address=[{'street': 'Sesame', 'number': 122}, {'street': 'Sesame', 'number': 122}], name='Cristian')
```

`Address` class can be avoided

Comment: could you give me an exmaple of how dataclasses make it more pythonic?.

Comment: updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I fully understand your question.
But if the problem is that you have a loop in the `__init__` method of the class you could solve it with a list comprehension. Something like:

```
self.address = [Address(*adr) for adr in address]
```

We now have still the loop, but is a bit cleaner

Answer (score 0):

I would also propose the [dataclass-wizard](https://github.com/rnag/dataclass-wizard) as an alternative when working with dataclasses; which works similarly to the accepted solution, but does not use the `marshmallow` library to generate schemas, for example.

```py
from __future__ import annotations

from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from typing import List

from dataclass_wizard import JSONWizard


@dataclass
class User(JSONWizard):
    address: List[Address] = field(default_factory=list)
    name: str = None

    def __str__(self):
        return "{0} ,{1}".format(self.name, self.address)


@dataclass
class Address:
    street: str
    number: int

    def __str__(self):
        return "{0} {1}".format(self.street, self.number)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    js = '''{
    "name": "Cristian",
    "address": [{
            "street": "Sesame",
            "number": 122
        },
        {
            "street": "Sesame",
            "number": 122
        }
    ]
    }'''

    data = User.from_json(js)
    print(data)
```

Output:

```
Cristian ,[Address(street='Sesame', number=122), Address(street='Sesame', number=122)]
```

Do note, that I've added a `__future__` import, primarily to support forward-declared annotations. If you want, you can remove that and instead declare the annotation for the `address` field, i.e. like `List['Address']`.