# How to create objects from a dict where the keys are the name objects and the values are the attributes? Using a loop

Tags: python, class, dictionary, for-loop

```
class Cars(object):

    def __init__(self,brand=None,color=None,cost=None):
        self.brand = brand
        self.color = color
        self.cost = cost
```

imagine i have 300 cars (from car1 to car300)

```
dict = {"car1":["Toyota","Red",10000],
        "car2":["Tesla","White",20000],
        "car3":["Honda","Red",15000] 
       }
```

What I have tried:

```
dict1 = globals()
for k,v in dict.items():
    dict1[f"{k}"] = Cars(v[0],v[1],v[2])
    print(k,v)
```

Is this the best possible way to do it?

Is this an aggressive way to do it?

I wold like to learn a efficient, safe way to do it

Comment: See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1305532/convert-nested-python-dict-to-object

Comment: Don't create dynamic variables. Put them in their own dictionary, not `globals()`

Comment: Is `Cars` supposed to be `Coche`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Close. First, you seem to have a name problem, `Cars` verses `Coche`. And you shouldn't use `dict` as a variable name. And you really need to consider whether putting these variables in the global namespace is a good idea. Besides that, you should not use an F string that doesn't add anything to the variable referenced. You can unpack the list with `*v` and you use a dict comprehension instead of a loop

```
my_dict = {k:Cars(*v) for k,v in dict.items()}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a dictionary for all the cars, not globals.

You can create it in one step with a dictionary comprehension.

```
all_cars = {name: Coche(brand, color, cost) for name, (brand, color, cost) in dict.items()}

print(all_cars['car1'].brand)
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the time ! and from that how can i call the objets..

Comment: print(car1.brand) doesn't work

Comment: I've updated the answer to show how to use the dictionary.