# Populate an object from a dictionary in python when object params are known

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have below an object:

```
class A:
    a:str
    b:str
    c:str
```

And the dictionary is as below:

`d = {"a":"abc","b":"def","d":"itf"}`

After populating the dictionary in the object, params `a` and `b` should be `"abc"` and `"def"` and `d` should be discarded and `c` should be None.

How can I achieve this?

**Edit**: i want to set instance attributes not class attributes in class A.

Comment: Are a, b and c instance or class variables?

Comment: You may find the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1305663/5165980

Comment: not instances but variables of class.

Comment: @Aymen in this answer, all keys will become params of object A. but i dont want key(d) of dictionary to part of object params.

Comment: `for x in A.__annotations__: setattr(A, x, d.get(x, None))`.

Comment: @ekhumoro can you please explain ? how can i use this ?

Comment: @MarifQ What do you mean? Just run that line of code as it is - there's nothing more to it (assuming `A` and `d` are defined as in your question, and you want to set *class* attributes, as opposed to *instance* attributes).

Comment: @ekhumoro maybe i didn't clear that in my question, my bad. but i want to set instance attributes not class attributes.

Comment: @MarifQ In that case, you can just replace `A` with the relevant instance variable to achieve exactly the same thing (which could be `self`, if you want to do this in `__init__` or a method of the class).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a classmethod to load each value from the dictionary into the specific class variable.

```
class A:
    a:str
    b:str
    c:str

    @classmethod
    def loadDict(cls, d:dict):
        cls.a = d.get("a", None)
        cls.b = d.get("b", None)
        cls.c = d.get("c", None)


d = {"a":"abc","b":"def","d":"itf"}

A.loadDict(d)
print(A.a) # "abc"
print(A.c) # None
```

Trying to get `A.d` results in an AttributeError.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a dict with the correct variables and update the class's `__dict__`

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        dictionary = {}
        for k, v in kwargs.items():
            if k in ["a", "b", "c"]:
                dictionary[k] = v

        self.a = None
        self.b = None
        self.c = None

        dictionary["c"] = None

        self.__dict__.update(**dictionary)


# define the dict with the variables and make the object
d = {"a": "abc", "b": "def", "d": "itf"}
objectWithDictVariables = A(**d)

# print the values from the object
print(objectWithDictVariables.__dict__["a"])
print(objectWithDictVariables.__dict__["b"])
print(objectWithDictVariables.__dict__["c"])
```